# Seeding the random number generator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, random, random-seed, seeding

Is it possible to seed the random number generator ([`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)) in JavaScript?

Comment: it is not clear whether you want to seed it so that you get the same results repeatedly for different test runs or whether you want to seed it with 'something unique' per user for better randomness between usage.

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not possible. [jsrand](https://github.com/DomenicoDeFelice/jsrand) is a little library I wrote when I needed a seedable PRNG. There are also other more complex libraries that you can find googling for it.

Comment: Adding to the question: how is it possibly a good idea to offer a PRNG without a means to seed it??  Is there any good reason for this?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292

Comment: Here's a visualization of some of the generators on this page https://observablehq.com/@tidwall/hello-randomness

Comment: @Alan I think maybe there's no seed because the underlying algorithm is up to the browser - if Math.random() did have a seed, the seeds would not be guaranteed to give the same results in different browsers. https://hackernoon.com/how-does-javascripts-math-random-generate-random-numbers-ef0de6a20131

Comment: @alan 99% of the time, what I want a random number generator for is to ... generate random numbers. Having to seed it is just an annoying extra step. A step that newbies might not realize they have to do and even experienced programmers might forget, and then they'll be baffled that the "random" numbers are always the same sequence. I am hard pressed to think of a time when I WANTED to determine the seed value.

Comment: @Jay You need a seed whenever you need to ensure complete replicability. In scientific programming, that is essentially always.

Comment: @Alan But in gaming and simulation, that is essentially never. The last thing you want in a game is replicability -- you want every play to be unique and unpredictable. You made the classic error here of jumping from "most of the time I want X" to "all of the time everybody wants X". If you want total reproducibility, why use a random number function at all? Why not just enter a list of numbers? The only time I've ever wanted reproducibility is when searching for a tricky bug.

Comment: @Jay If you do not seed the generator, adequate testing becomes difficult. When the need arises, you can always seed the generator randomly. In any case, it is not that everyone needs to seed every time. The less scientific the usage, the less it matters. My point is that a good generator allows seeding because many people need that, even if you believe you do not.

Comment: @alan Exactly. If you need to seed a random number generator with a known value for testing, well good for you, but I think that puts you among a tiny minority of users of an RNG. I have been programming for over 40 years and I've only had a handful of times when this was useful. If you run into this situation every day, okay, fine. But that's why I quibble with your statement "how is it possibly a good idea ... ?" It's a good idea because 99% of the time there is no value to seeding the RNG with a known number. If your coding is an exception to that, okay, fine.

Comment: It's like saying, "Why in the world would someone sell a car without a trailer hitch? I always tow a trailer everywhere I go. A car without a trailer hitch is useless." Useless to you maybe, but not useless to 99% of drivers.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

No, it is not possible to seed `Math.random()`, but it's fairly easy to write your own generator, or better yet, use an existing one.

Check out: [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/how-to-create-my-own-javascript-random-number-generator-that-i-can-also-set-the-s).

Also, see David Bau's blog for [more information on seeding](http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html#more).

Answer (score 473):

No, it is not possible to seed `Math.random()`. The [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-math.random) is intentionally vague on the subject, providing no means for seeding nor require that browsers even use the same algorithm. So such a function must be externally provided, which thankfully isn't too difficult.

I've implemented a number of good, short and fast **Pseudorandom number generator** (PRNG) functions in plain JavaScript. All of them can be seeded and provide high quality numbers. These are not intended for security purposes--if you need a seedable CSPRNG, look into [ISAAC](https://github.com/macmcmeans/isaacCSPRNG).

**First of all, take care to initialize your PRNGs properly.** To keep things simple, the generators below have no built-in seed generating procedure, but accept one or more 32-bit numbers as the initial *seed state* of the PRNG. Similar or sparse seeds (e.g. a simple seed of 1 and 2) have low entropy, and can cause correlations or other randomness quality issues, sometimes resulting in the output having similar properties (such as randomly generated levels being similar). To avoid this, it is best practice to initialize PRNGs with a well-distributed, high entropy seed and/or advancing past the first 15 or so numbers.

There are many ways to do this, but here are two methods. Firstly, [hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) are very good at generating seeds from short strings. A good hash function will generate very different results even when two strings are similar, so you don't have to put much thought into the string. Here's an example hash function:

```
function cyrb128(str) {
    let h1 = 1779033703, h2 = 3144134277,
        h3 = 1013904242, h4 = 2773480762;
    for (let i = 0, k; i < str.length; i++) {
        k = str.charCodeAt(i);
        h1 = h2 ^ Math.imul(h1 ^ k, 597399067);
        h2 = h3 ^ Math.imul(h2 ^ k, 2869860233);
        h3 = h4 ^ Math.imul(h3 ^ k, 951274213);
        h4 = h1 ^ Math.imul(h4 ^ k, 2716044179);
    }
    h1 = Math.imul(h3 ^ (h1 >>> 18), 597399067);
    h2 = Math.imul(h4 ^ (h2 >>> 22), 2869860233);
    h3 = Math.imul(h1 ^ (h3 >>> 17), 951274213);
    h4 = Math.imul(h2 ^ (h4 >>> 19), 2716044179);
    h1 ^= (h2 ^ h3 ^ h4), h2 ^= h1, h3 ^= h1, h4 ^= h1;
    return [h1>>>0, h2>>>0, h3>>>0, h4>>>0];
}
// Side note: Only designed & tested for seed generation,
// may be suboptimal as a general 128-bit hash.
```

Calling `cyrb128` will produce a 128-bit hash value from a string which can be used to seed a PRNG. Here's how you might use it:

```
// Create cyrb128 state:
var seed = cyrb128("apples");
// Four 32-bit component hashes provide the seed for sfc32.
var rand = sfc32(seed[0], seed[1], seed[2], seed[3]);

// Or... only one 32-bit component hash is needed for splitmix32.
var rand = splitmix32(seed[0]);

// You can now generate repeatable sequences of random numbers:
rand(); // 0.8865117691457272
rand(); // 0.24518639338202775
```

*Note: If you want a slightly more robust 128-bit hash, consider [MurmurHash3_x86_128](https://github.com/bryc/code/blob/master/jshash/hashes/murmurhash3_128.js), it's more thorough, but intended for use with large arrays. Since this operates on byte arrays, strings require conversion using something like `Array.from("hello", c=>c.charCodeAt())`.*

Alternatively, simply choose some dummy data to pad the seed with, and advance the generator beforehand a few times (12-20 iterations) to mix the initial state thoroughly. This has the benefit of being simpler, and is often used in reference implementations of PRNGs, but it does limit the number of initial states:

```
var seed = 1337 ^ 0xDEADBEEF; // 32-bit seed with optional XOR value
// Pad seed with Phi, Pi and E.
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing-up-my-sleeve_number
var rand = sfc32(0x9E3779B9, 0x243F6A88, 0xB7E15162, seed);
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) rand();
```

Note: the output of these PRNG functions produce a positive 32-bit number (0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1) which is then converted to a floating-point number between 0-1 (0 inclusive, 1 exclusive) equivalent to `Math.random()`, if you want random numbers of a specific range, read [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random). If you only want the raw bits, simply remove the final division operation.

JavaScript numbers can only represent whole integers up to 53-bit resolution. And when using bitwise operations, this is reduced to 32. Modern PRNGs in other languages often use 64-bit operations, which require shims when porting to JS that can *drastically* reduce performance. The algorithms here only use 32-bit operations, as it is directly compatible with JS.

> Now, onward to the the generators. *(I maintain the full list with references and license info [here](https://github.com/bryc/code/blob/master/jshash/PRNGs.md))*

---

#### sfc32 (Simple Fast Counter)

**sfc32** is part of the [PractRand](http://pracrand.sourceforge.net/) random number testing suite (which it passes of course). sfc32 has a 128-bit state and is very fast in JS.

```js
function sfc32(a, b, c, d) {
  return function() {
    a |= 0; b |= 0; c |= 0; d |= 0;
    let t = (a + b | 0) + d | 0;
    d = d + 1 | 0;
    a = b ^ b >>> 9;
    b = c + (c << 3) | 0;
    c = (c << 21 | c >>> 11);
    c = c + t | 0;
    return (t >>> 0) / 4294967296;
  }
}

const r = () => Math.random();
const now = Date.now();
const prng = sfc32(now * r(), now * r(), now * r(), now * r());
for(let i=0; i<10; i++) console.log(prng());
```

You may wonder what the `| 0` and `>>>= 0` are for. These are essentially 32-bit integer casts, used for performance optimizations. `Number` in JS are basically floats, but during bitwise operations, they switch into a 32-bit integer mode. This mode is processed faster by JS interpreters, but any multiplication or addition will cause it to switch back to a float, resulting in a performance hit.

#### SplitMix32

A 32-bit state PRNG that was made by taking MurmurHash3's mixing function, adding a incrementor and tweaking the constants. It's potentially one of the best 32-bit PRNGs so far; even the author of Mulberry32 [considers it to be the better choice](https://gist.github.com/tommyettinger/46a874533244883189143505d203312c?permalink_comment_id=4365431#gistcomment-4365431). It's also just as fast.

```js
function splitmix32(a) {
 return function() {
   a |= 0;
   a = a + 0x9e3779b9 | 0;
   let t = a ^ a >>> 16;
   t = Math.imul(t, 0x21f0aaad);
   t = t ^ t >>> 15;
   t = Math.imul(t, 0x735a2d97);
   return ((t = t ^ t >>> 15) >>> 0) / 4294967296;
  }
}

const prng = splitmix32(Date.now() * Math.random())
for(let i=0; i<10; i++) console.log(prng());
```

I would recommend this if you just need a simple but *good* PRNG and don't need billions of random numbers (see [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)).

#### Mulberry32

Mulberry32 is a simple generator with a 32-bit state, but is extremely fast and has acceptable quality randomness (author states it passes all tests of [gjrand](http://gjrand.sourceforge.net/) testing suite and has a full 2<sup>32</sup> period, but I haven't verified).

```js
function mulberry32(a) {
  return function() {
    let t = a += 0x6D2B79F5;
    t = Math.imul(t ^ t >>> 15, t | 1);
    t ^= t + Math.imul(t ^ t >>> 7, t | 61);
    return ((t ^ t >>> 14) >>> 0) / 4294967296;
  }
}

const prng = mulberry32(Date.now() * Math.random())
for(let i=0; i<10; i++) console.log(prng());
```

#### xoshiro128**

**xoshiro128**** (Vigna & Blackman, 2018) is part of the [Xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) lineage (Vigna was also responsible for the Xorshift128+ algorithm powering most `Math.random` implementations under the hood). It is the fastest generator that offers a 128-bit state.

```js
function xoshiro128ss(a, b, c, d) {
  return function() {
    let t = b << 9, r = b * 5;
    r = (r << 7 | r >>> 25) * 9;
    c ^= a;
    d ^= b;
    b ^= c;
    a ^= d;
    c ^= t;
    d = d << 11 | d >>> 21;
    return (r >>> 0) / 4294967296;
  }
}

const r = () => Math.random();
const now = Date.now();
const prng = xoshiro128ss(now * r(), now * r(), now * r(), now * r());
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(prng());
```

The authors claim it passes randomness tests well ([albeit with caveats](http://prng.di.unimi.it/)). Other researchers have pointed out that it fails some tests in TestU01 (particularly LinearComp and BinaryRank). In practice, it should not cause issues when floats are used (such as in these implementations), but may cause issues if relying on the raw lowest order bit.

#### JSF (Jenkins' Small Fast)

This is JSF or 'smallprng' by Bob Jenkins (2007), who also made [ISAAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISAAC_(cipher)) and [SpookyHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function#SpookyHash). It [passes](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bob-jenkins-small-prng-passes-practrand.html) PractRand tests and should be quite fast, although not as fast as sfc32.

```js
function jsf32(a, b, c, d) {
  return function() {
    a |= 0; b |= 0; c |= 0; d |= 0;
    let t = a - (b << 27 | b >>> 5) | 0;
    a = b ^ (c << 17 | c >>> 15);
    b = c + d | 0;
    c = d + t | 0;
    d = a + t | 0;
    return (d >>> 0) / 4294967296;
  }
}

const r = () => Math.random();
const now = Date.now();
const prng = jsf32(now * r(), now * r(), now * r(), now * r());
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(prng());
```

Comment: Are these all inclusive of 0 and exclusive of 1?

Comment: I believe the values you quoted from "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators..." by Pierre L’ecuyer could exceed the maximum integer size in Javascript. The max seed of (2^32-1) * 741103597 ≈ 3e18, which is greater than JavaScript's max int size of ≈ 9e15. I think the following values from Pierre's book have the largest period within native limits: `seed = (seed * 185852 + 1) % 34359738337`.

Comment: @Lachmanski true, but those are bound by 32-bits (and the Park-Miller 31-bits). Using `Math.imul` allows it to overflow as it would when using multiplication in C on 32-bit integers. What you're suggesting is an LCG utilizing the full range of JS's integer space, which is definitely an interesting area to explore as well. :)

Comment: This is awesome! Can I just copy your sfc32 into an LGPL program?

Comment: Sure, feel free to use the code for whatever purpose :)

Comment: Would be nice to have these examples on a page that can be cited without SO in the url (for attribution)

Comment: @blobber2 not sure what you mean, but the original code is from here (with others): https://github.com/bryc/code/blob/master/jshash/PRNGs.md. more or less a gist inside a repository :-)

Comment: thanks for the very useful post! are the a >>>= 0 and a |= 0 some fast ways of casting to 32 bit int?

Comment: @DrLightman correct - forcing it early, or keeping it always in 32-bit, appears to speed things up. Although now I forget how exactly I measured them. But it could easily be obsolete in the future as JS engines might get smarter. But even now, this example shows that fnv1a hash is 70% slower without `| 0`, in firefox: https://jsbench.me/afk9jv36oz/1.

Comment: Thanks for the research that went into this, bryc! It still took me a bit to figure out which to use and how to generate an integer 0-n (first used Math.round, tested it, didn't give good results, then used Math.floor, that worked). Maybe add to the "apples" example: `n = Math.floor(rand() * X); // generate random integer below X`? For choosing an algorithm, e.g. JSF says it performs "well" (others perform "without issue", is that better?) and "should" be fast. I see in git you have the numbers, it might help to be more concrete here. Either way, your answer helped me, thanks for the work!

Comment: @Luc Thanks, glad it was a help! Some valid criticisms here - I'll add link to MDN for doing ranged numbers. JSF and SFC both pass PractRand, but JSF is a bit slower - I just wrote general observations. I don't want the answer to be TOO long. But I will see if I can make it less confusing. :)

Comment: @bryc I see you did quite some work on the post! The MDN reference is a good idea, I didn't know of that page (would have saved me the trial-and-error :) ). One question: "*these are all 32-bit generators*" and a bit later "*sfc32 has a 128-bit state*". Isn't that a contradiction (probably leftover from the previous revision)?

Comment: @Luc No, that's correct. These algorithms are ported from 32-bit C code, intended for older 32-bit CPUs. "128-bit state" is just the internal memory size, and implies a collection of four 32-bit words acting as one unit. In JS, bitwise operations are bound by 32-bit words, which is why 32-bit C code can be ported to JS efficiently. Hope that explains it

Comment: @bryc So if I understand it correctly, the period will be 2^128 and the "they're all 32-bit" is meant to convey that the algorithms can efficiently be ported from their original C to JavaScript? Because what I guess people care about is the period, not so much how hard the porting work was. Thanks again, by the way :)

Comment: @Luc The state size doesn't define the period, only theoretical max. A minimum period of 2^32 is sufficient for non-cryptographic use. JSF and SFC have an avg period of 2^127 (according to PractRand) which is quite good. And I mention "32-bit" because it is important to understand. Something like [PCG](https://github.com/thomcc/pcg-random/blob/master/pcg-random.js) by its very nature, is inefficient/slow in JS (my goal here is efficiency/speed). It takes more code to reimplement 64-bit multiplication than _any_ of the above PRNGs, and end up running exponentially slower.

Comment: Thanks for this code. I do question the use of xmur3 to initialize sfc32. You're initializing 128 bits of seed with only 32 bits of entropy. I think it's better to use a hash that produces a larger result.

Comment: @Vroo I'm not that concerned, _PRNG quality > seed quality_, and it is somewhat unavoidable. Due to JS bitwise limitations, 32-bit results must be mixed together. Have a look at [MurmurHash3_x86_128](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/blob/master/src/MurmurHash3.cpp#L150) - four uncorrelated 32-bit hashes sufficiently mixed produce valid 128-bit hashes. If improved mixing of component hashes does not increase entropy, as used in MurmurHash3_x86_128, then nothing can be done about it~

Comment: My point @bryc was that you're not using "four uncorrelated 32-bit hashes," you're using four correlated hashes since xmur3 only has 32 bits of internal state. I'm using your port of sfc32 (thanks!) and am initializing it with a 128 bit hash instead.

Comment: @Vroo `xmur3` is indeed correlated, there's no denying that -  I was referring to the linked 128-bit hash implementation which was uncorrelated. Unfortunately fixing xmur3 would require quadrupling the code size. Which 128-bit hash are you using? I have not seen much of those in JS.

Comment: In xmur3, maybe put the first two lines of the for loop in braces for clarity? (I misread the comma for a semicolon and was confused, but maybe it's only me)

Comment: Can I use this in crypto context?

Comment: @Ted No, these are not secure PRNGs. Use the built-in `Crypto.getRandomValues()` for secure random values, but note it cannot be seeded (AFAIK). If you absolutely must have repeatable results for some reason, try [ISAAC](https://github.com/rubycon/isaac.js/blob/master/isaac.js), but it wont be as fast and take up more code.

Comment: @Vroo 2 years later, I've now replaced `xmur3` with an intermixed 128-bit hash. Hopefully its not much worse than `MurmurHash3_x86_128`. Sorry I didn't quite grasp your entropy concern before, I now realize it was misleading to suggest it for initializing a 128-bit state.

Comment: And where does this cyrb128 come from ?

Comment: @jdbertron It's a hash function I made, similar to [cyrb53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript/47593316#47593316) but outputs 128 bits instead of 53.

Comment: Looks useful. Could you cite sources so we can verify that your implementation matches the design?

Comment: Hmm. Actually, your jsf does NOT match the design of https://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/smallprng.html in three ways: (1) it converts to a floating-point value, (2) it does not take a 32-bit seed used for b,c,d with `a=0xf1ea5eed`, and (3) it does not perform the initial 20 loops to "mix" the random state.

Comment: @JasonS (1) Returning float is just to match Math.random output; easily removed if needed. (2,3) Goal is not to provide ready-made libs, but to teach/explain the craft and only provide base generators, while explaining seeding separately. I _do_ provide the original seed procedures (and references) in the [long-form article](https://github.com/bryc/code/blob/master/jshash/PRNGs.md#jsf--smallprng). But it is optional, and using a custom seed generator still retains the quality of the generator, and is sometimes better (larger seed space, etc).

Comment: Yes but you state "This is JSF or 'smallprng' by Bob Jenkins (2007)." Could you please state that you have a RNG that is based on JSF/smallprng? There is a difference.

Comment: it's worth nothing that the xoshiro128** implementation in this answer is based on the 1.0 reference code which [mistakenly used s\[0\] instead of s\[1\] as state word passed to the scrambler](https://prng.di.unimi.it/xoshiro128starstar.c)

Comment: @relative fixed. didnt know that was an issue.

Comment: @Boddle I updated `cyrb128` to fix the issue you found. Indeed, what I had was satisfying this equation `(A ^ B ^ C ^ D) === ((A^B) ^ (A^C) ^ (A^D))`, which I guess it shouldn't have. The new solution is similar to what `MurmurHash3_x86_128` does. Also, you should have just commented instead of posting it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 218):

NOTE: Despite (or rather, because of) succinctness and apparent elegance, this algorithm is by no means a high-quality one in terms of randomness. Look for e.g. those listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript/47593316#47593316) for better results.

(Originally adapted from a clever idea presented in a comment to another answer.)

```
var seed = 1;
function random() {
    var x = Math.sin(seed++) * 10000;
    return x - Math.floor(x);
}
```

You can set `seed` to be any number, just avoid zero (or any multiple of Math.PI).

The elegance of this solution, in my opinion, comes from the lack of any "magic" numbers (besides 10000, which represents about the minimum amount of digits you must throw away to avoid odd patterns - see results with values [10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIHGJ.png), [100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkqhu.png), [1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV3K5.png)).  Brevity is also nice.

It's a bit slower than Math.random() (by a factor of 2 or 3), but I believe it's about as fast as any other solution written in JavaScript.

Comment: Is there a way to prove this RNG generate numbers that are uniformly distributed? Experimentally it seems to: http://jsfiddle.net/bhrLT/

Comment: [6,000,000 ops/second](http://jsperf.com/math-random-vs-seeded-rand) is pretty fast, I don't plan on generating more than ~3,000,000 per click. Kidding, this is brilliant.

Comment: Actually, the smaller the number is, the faster it runs.  A Math.random decimal gets ~20,000,000 ops/second. I just updated the jsperf.   Either way, this probably won't be a bottleneck in your application.

Comment: -1, This isn't a uniform sampler at all - it is quite biased towards 0 and 1 (see http://jsfiddle.net/bhrLT/17/, which may take a while to compute). Consecutive values are correlated - every 355 values, and even more so every 710, are related. Please use something more carefully thought-out!

Comment: @kharybdis change the 10000 to 1000000 and it looks better

Comment: @JasonGoemaat, that's just taking a few extra decimals from the sin function - it's not resolving the core problem, which is that the decimals of sin aren't uniformly distributed. It looks better, but thats just because you need more datapoints to see the nonuniformity.

Comment: The question's not about creating a cryptographically secure random number generator, but something that works in javascript, useful for quick demos, etc.  I'll take something quick and simple that gives a good looking distribution over a million random numbers for that purpose.

Comment: Looking at the histogram spencer nelson posted, it looks like the uniformity could easily be improved by discarding results outside the range, say [0.1,0.9], and normalising the remaining results from that range to [0,1].

Comment: Jason Goemaat : Actualy any mod operation can fit the answer in that case, and for that matter only using sin(x) or mod(x,...) is the same. That's not random number, you can also use permutation to even go faster. The question is then misleading if tricks like this are accepted. I am downvoting it. A random generator should show any correlation, nor frequency pattern, it's stupid.

Comment: Be careful. Math.sin() can give different results on client and server. I use Meteor (uses javascript on client & server).

Comment: @realh Exactly! http://jsfiddle.net/Llorx/bhrLT/93/ Still not 100% secure for crypto, but the result is more normalized.

Comment: This does create different results on different browsers... chrome, safari firefox all have different results. so if the purpose is to use the seed for consistency, this won't work.

Comment: Nitpicking this answer for what it is, is not right.

Comment: It’s far from uniform and far from independent. Mathematically speaking, it is ergodic but not even mixing. It will fail the most basic tests involving LLN and CLT.

Comment: There's more correlation to 355 then 710 because it a continued fraction of pi:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Continued_fraction_expansions_of_%CF%80 @spencernelson

Comment: Wouldn't you get a (slightly) better distribution going for Math.tan() instead of Math.sin()? http://jsfiddle.net/g7f9jqr4/2/

Answer (score 53):

No, but here's a simple pseudorandom generator, an implementation of [Multiply-with-carry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry_pseudorandom_number_generator) I adapted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) (has been removed since):

```
var m_w = 123456789;
var m_z = 987654321;
var mask = 0xffffffff;

// Takes any integer
function seed(i) {
    m_w = (123456789 + i) & mask;
    m_z = (987654321 - i) & mask;
}

// Returns number between 0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive),
// just like Math.random().
function random()
{
    m_z = (36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >> 16)) & mask;
    m_w = (18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >> 16)) & mask;
    var result = ((m_z << 16) + (m_w & 65535)) >>> 0;
    result /= 4294967296;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Has anyone tested this function for its randomness?

Comment: This is the [multiply-with-carry (MWC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply-with-carry) random generator with a pretty long period. Adapted from [wikipedia Random Number Generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Computational_methods)

Comment: When I use it with my random color generator (HSL), it generates only green and cyan colors. The original random generator generates all colors. So, it is not same or it does not work.

Comment: @Michael_Scharf 1) The seed change `m_w`, not `m_z`. 2) Both `m_w` and `m_z` are change BASED on their previous values, so it does modify the result.

Comment: When I used this code I did not get well-distributed results. Regardless of seed, the output sequence was very similar. This made it not helpful for my game.

Comment: @Justin this is several years too late, but with several seeds at millions of runs, it's almost perfectly distributed. Variance in distribution was around `3.469446951953614e-18` - i.e. _extremely_ well distributed. [This](https://gist.github.com/Qix-/c01d144472593a27d398619ad6e54c03) is the script I used to test distribution. Just needs an object with a `next()` method.

Comment: Changing the seed does not result in a completely different sequence of random numbers, there is some sort of underlying pattern. This is the [XOR of two bit graphs](https://i.imgur.com/ly3Y1Pk.png) with seed 1 and 55. White pixels are <0.5, black pixels are >0.5. XORing two outputs with different seeds show a bias towards >0.5.

Comment: I provided an edit to address some serious issues in the code. It was not being properly seeded, and the workaround for negative numbers was causing bias. This is very similar to the MWC1616 algorithm which has a [bad reputation](https://medium.com/@betable/tifu-by-using-math-random-f1c308c4fd9d) as far as quality goes.

Comment: Is this method secure enough? Can I use this function in crypto context?

Answer (score 34):

Antti Sykäri's algorithm is nice and short. I initially made a variation that replaced JavaScript's `Math.random` when you call `Math.seed(s)`, but then Jason commented that returning the function would be better:

```
Math.seed = function(s) {
    return function() {
        s = Math.sin(s) * 10000; return s - Math.floor(s);
    };
};

// usage:
var random1 = Math.seed(42);
var random2 = Math.seed(random1());
Math.random = Math.seed(random2());
```

This gives you another functionality that JavaScript doesn't have: multiple independent random generators. That is especially important if you want to have multiple repeatable simulations running at the same time.

Comment: If you return the function instead of setting `Math.random` that would allow you to have multiple independent generators, right?

Comment: Be sure to see comments above about distribution of randomness if that matters to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/javascript-random-seeds#comment36604417_19303725

Comment: How randoms generated by this can be repeated? It keeps giving new numbers every time

Comment: each time you do `Math.seed(42);` it resets the function, so if you do `var random = Math.seed(42); random(); random();` you get `0.70...`, then `0.38...`. If you reset it by calling `var random = Math.seed(42);` again, then the next time you call `random()` you'll get `0.70...` again, and the next time you'll get `0.38...` again.

Comment: Please do not use this. Please take the time to instead use a local variable named `random` instead of overwriting a native javascript function. Overwriting `Math.random` may cause the JIST compiler to unoptimize all your code.

Comment: Warning not working for s = 0. Should throw error when constructing.

Comment: This answer adds nothing of value.

Answer (score 12):

Please see Pierre L'Ecuyer's work going back to the late 1980s and early 1990s. There are others as well. Creating a (pseudo) random number generator on your own, if you are not an expert, is pretty dangerous, because there is a high likelihood of either the results not being statistically random or in having a small period. Pierre (and others) have put together some good (pseudo) random number generators that are easy to implement. I use one of his LFSR generators.

[https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/handstat.pdf](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Elecuyer/myftp/papers/handstat.pdf)

Comment: Great answer, but not related to javascript :)

Comment: The code for implementing Professor L'Ecuyer's work is publicly available for java and readily translatable by most programmers into Javascript.

Answer (score 11):

It's not possible to seed the builtin Math.random function, but it is possible to implement a high quality RNG in Javascript with very little code.

Javascript numbers are 64-bit floating point precision, which can represent all positive integers less than 2^53. This puts a hard limit to our arithmetic, but within these limits you can still pick parameters for a high quality Lehmer / LCG random number generator.

```
function RNG(seed) {
    var m = 2**35 - 31
    var a = 185852
    var s = seed % m
    return function () {
        return (s = s * a % m) / m
    }
}

Math.random = RNG(Date.now())
```

If you want even higher quality random numbers, at the cost of being ~10 times slower, you can use BigInt for the arithmetic and pick parameters where m is just able to fit in a double.

```
function RNG(seed) {
    var m_as_number = 2**53 - 111
    var m = 2n**53n - 111n
    var a = 5667072534355537n
    var s = BigInt(seed) % m
    return function () {
        return Number(s = s * a % m) / m_as_number
    }
}
```

See this paper by Pierre l'Ecuyer for the parameters used in the above implementations:
https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-00996-5/S0025-5718-99-00996-5.pdf

And whatever you do, avoid all the other answers here that use Math.sin!

Comment: Why is m=2 * * 35 ?   To use full range of integer values should it be m=Math.floor(2 * * 53 / a)?

Comment: The values of m and a are chosen together to produce a sequence that looks random. If you pick bad values you might end up with a RANDU situation. See the paper referenced in the answer and the ACM article "Random number generators: good ones are hard to find" by Park & Miller (can be found on scihub).

Answer (score 8):

Combining some of the previous answers, this is the seedable random function you are looking for:

```
Math.seed = function(s) {
    var mask = 0xffffffff;
    var m_w  = (123456789 + s) & mask;
    var m_z  = (987654321 - s) & mask;

    return function() {
      m_z = (36969 * (m_z & 65535) + (m_z >>> 16)) & mask;
      m_w = (18000 * (m_w & 65535) + (m_w >>> 16)) & mask;

      var result = ((m_z << 16) + (m_w & 65535)) >>> 0;
      result /= 4294967296;
      return result;
    }
}

var myRandomFunction = Math.seed(1234);
var randomNumber = myRandomFunction();
```

Comment: This produces very similar results at the beginning of the sequence with different seeds.  For example, `Math.seed(0)()` returns `0.2322845458984375`, and `Math.seed(1)()` returns `0.23228873685002327`.  Changing both `m_w` and `m_z` according to the seed seems to help.  `var m_w  = 987654321 + s;
    var m_z  = 123456789 - s;` produces a nice distribution of first values with different seeds.

Comment: @undefined the issue you described is fixed as of the last edit, it was a bug in the MWC implementation.

Comment: Working nicely now, as of Jan 2020. Seed with 0, get 0.7322976540308446. Seed with 1, 0.16818441334180534, with 2: 0.6040864314418286, with 3: 
0.03998844954185188. Thank you both!

Comment: I'm curious about the `>>> 0` and why it's better than the more straightforward `& mask`.

Answer (score 6):

To write your own pseudo random generator is quite simple.

The suggestion of Dave Scotese is useful but, as pointed out by others, it is not quite uniformly distributed.

However, it is not because of the integer arguments of sin. It's simply because of the range of sin, which happens to be a one dimensional projection of a circle. If you would take the angle of the circle instead it would be uniform.

So instead of `sin(x)` use `arg(exp(i * x)) / (2 * PI)`.

If you don't like the linear order, mix it a bit up with xor. The actual factor doesn't matter that much either.

To generate n pseudo random numbers one could use the code:

```
function psora(k, n) {
  var r = Math.PI * (k ^ n)
  return r - Math.floor(r)
}
n = 42; for(k = 0; k < n; k++) console.log(psora(k, n))
```

Please also note that you cannot use pseudo random sequences when real entropy is needed.

Comment: I'm no expert, but sequential seeds follow a [constant pattern](http://i.imgur.com/LObOzxB.png). Colored pixels are >= 0.5. I am guessing its just iterating over the radius over and over?

Comment: "To write your own pseudo random generator is quite simple." -- But to write a correct pseudo random generator is not.

Answer (score 3):

Many people who need a seedable random-number generator in Javascript these days are using [David Bau's seedrandom module](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom).

Answer (score 3):

`Math.random` no, but the [*ran* library](https://synesenom.github.io/ran/) solves this. It has almost all distributions you can imagine and supports seeded random number generation. Example:

```
ran.core.seed(0)
myDist = new ran.Dist.Uniform(0, 1)
samples = myDist.sample(1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, like they said it is not possible to seed Math.random()
but you can install external package which make provision for that. i used these package  which can be install using these command

```
npm i random-seed
```

the example is gotten from the package documentation.

```
var seed = 'Hello World',
rand1 = require('random-seed').create(seed),
rand2 = require('random-seed').create(seed);
console.log(rand1(100), rand2(100));
```

follow the link for documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-seed

Answer (score 1):

Here's the adopted version of Jenkins hash, borrowed from [here](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/5670917)

```
export function createDeterministicRandom(): () => number {
  let seed = 0x2F6E2B1;
  return function() {
    // Robert Jenkins’ 32 bit integer hash function
    seed = ((seed + 0x7ED55D16) + (seed << 12))  & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    seed = ((seed ^ 0xC761C23C) ^ (seed >>> 19)) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    seed = ((seed + 0x165667B1) + (seed << 5))   & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    seed = ((seed + 0xD3A2646C) ^ (seed << 9))   & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    seed = ((seed + 0xFD7046C5) + (seed << 3))   & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    seed = ((seed ^ 0xB55A4F09) ^ (seed >>> 16)) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    return (seed & 0xFFFFFFF) / 0x10000000;
  };
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
const deterministicRandom = createDeterministicRandom()
deterministicRandom()
// => 0.9872818551957607

deterministicRandom()
// => 0.34880331158638
```

Answer (score 1):

SIN(id + seed) is a very interesting replacement for RANDOM functions that cannot be seeded like SQLite:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75089040/7776828

Answer (score 1):

Do what bryc suggests ... but before you use his cyrb128 hash function to initialise, note that the return statement throws away 32 bits of entropy. Exclusive-or the four values together = 0.  You should probably make the first element (h2^h3^h4) >>> 0.

Comment: That's a bug. Fixed. though you should have made a comment instead of a separate answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgment, bryc, I agree but not enough reputation to comment

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here produce biased results. So here's a tested function based on [seedrandom library from github](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom):

```
!function(f,a,c){var s,l=256,p="random",d=c.pow(l,6),g=c.pow(2,52),y=2*g,h=l-1;function n(n,t,r){function e(){for(var n=u.g(6),t=d,r=0;n<g;)n=(n+r)*l,t*=l,r=u.g(1);for(;y<=n;)n/=2,t/=2,r>>>=1;return(n+r)/t}var o=[],i=j(function n(t,r){var e,o=[],i=typeof t;if(r&&"object"==i)for(e in t)try{o.push(n(t[e],r-1))}catch(n){}return o.length?o:"string"==i?t:t+"\0"}((t=1==t?{entropy:!0}:t||{}).entropy?[n,S(a)]:null==n?function(){try{var n;return s&&(n=s.randomBytes)?n=n(l):(n=new Uint8Array(l),(f.crypto||f.msCrypto).getRandomValues(n)),S(n)}catch(n){var t=f.navigator,r=t&&t.plugins;return[+new Date,f,r,f.screen,S(a)]}}():n,3),o),u=new m(o);return e.int32=function(){return 0|u.g(4)},e.quick=function(){return u.g(4)/4294967296},e.double=e,j(S(u.S),a),(t.pass||r||function(n,t,r,e){return e&&(e.S&&v(e,u),n.state=function(){return v(u,{})}),r?(c[p]=n,t):n})(e,i,"global"in t?t.global:this==c,t.state)}function m(n){var t,r=n.length,u=this,e=0,o=u.i=u.j=0,i=u.S=[];for(r||(n=[r++]);e<l;)i[e]=e++;for(e=0;e<l;e++)i[e]=i[o=h&o+n[e%r]+(t=i[e])],i[o]=t;(u.g=function(n){for(var t,r=0,e=u.i,o=u.j,i=u.S;n--;)t=i[e=h&e+1],r=r*l+i[h&(i[e]=i[o=h&o+t])+(i[o]=t)];return u.i=e,u.j=o,r})(l)}function v(n,t){return t.i=n.i,t.j=n.j,t.S=n.S.slice(),t}function j(n,t){for(var r,e=n+"",o=0;o<e.length;)t[h&o]=h&(r^=19*t[h&o])+e.charCodeAt(o++);return S(t)}function S(n){return String.fromCharCode.apply(0,n)}if(j(c.random(),a),"object"==typeof module&&module.exports){module.exports=n;try{s=require("crypto")}catch(n){}}else"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(function(){return n}):c["seed"+p]=n}("undefined"!=typeof self?self:this,[],Math);

function randIntWithSeed(seed, max=1) {
  /* returns a random number between [0,max] including zero and max
  seed can be either string or integer */
  return Math.round(new Math.seedrandom('seed' + seed)()) * max
}
```

test for true randomness of this code: https://es6console.com/kkjkgur2/

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of good answers here but I had a similar issue with the additional requirement that I would like portability between Java's random number generator and whatever I ended up using in JavaScript.

I found the [java-random package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/java-random)

These two pieces of code had identical output assuming the seed is the same:

Java:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random(seed);
int randomInt;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(50);
    System.out.println(randomInt);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
let Random = require('java-random');
let rng = new Random(seed);
for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
    let val = rng.nextInt(50);
    console.log(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After an enlightening discussion with two of my former maths teachers, I reworked [Antti Kissaniemi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19303725/11126680) for the joke. At first, of course, they cried out in distress. Then they made the effort to try and understand to explain to me the bias towards 0 and 1 in the original answer.

Then they told me that they "*see no reason why the original proposal would be interesting. In this case, sine exactly breaks the property we want to obtain: it destroys uniformity and that's why you have to multiply by 10000 afterwards*".

They proposed a same-level solution: using an integer directly, divide it by PI, and return the fractional part.

```
let seed = 1;
function random() {
    let x = seed++ / Math.PI;
    return x - Math.floor(x);
}
```

And it seems to be generally slightly more performant, without the bias, still uniform. https://jsperf.app/xoxato

## Testing

To add some seriousness to the joke, we can use [PractRand with M.E. O'Neill tips](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/how-to-test-with-practrand.html) to test our seeded generator. Using this C++ snippet:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
# define M_PI   3.14159265358979323846

// ECMAScript 2024 Math.PI value is approximately 3.1415926535897932

uint32_t seed = 1;

double rdm() {
    double x = seed++ / M_PI;
    return x - std::floor(x);
}

int main() {
    while (1) {
        double randomValue = rdm() * static_cast<double>(std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max());
        uint32_t value = static_cast<uint32_t>(randomValue);
        fwrite((void*)&value, sizeof(value), 1, stdout);
    }
}
```

Then follow the blog post instructions:

```
$ ./pitest | ./RNG_test stdin32
RNG_test using PractRand version 0.93
RNG = RNG_stdin32, seed = 0xcdbb7f8d
test set = normal, folding = standard (32 bit)

rng=RNG_stdin32, seed=0xcdbb7f8d
length= 256 megabytes (2^28 bytes), time= 3.5 seconds
  Test Name                         Raw       Processed     Evaluation
  BCFN(2+0,13-2,T)                  R=+2083708 p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+1,13-2,T)                  R=+1922191 p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+2,13-3,T)                  R=+2225045 p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+3,13-3,T)                  R=+1873278 p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+4,13-3,T)                  R=+1254072 p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+5,13-4,T)                  R=+925525 p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+6,13-5,T)                  R=+599006 p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+7,13-5,T)                  R=+303954 p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+8,13-6,T)                  R=+189477 p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+9,13-6,T)                  R=+94177  p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+10,13-7,T)                 R=+56830  p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+11,13-8,T)                 R=+33230  p =  1e-8434    FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+12,13-8,T)                 R=+16547  p =  2e-4200    FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+13,13-9,T)                 R= +9358  p =  7e-2104    FAIL !!!!!!!!
  BCFN(2+14,13-9,T)                 R= +4657  p =  1e-1047    FAIL !!!!!!!!
  DC6-9x1Bytes-1                    R=+522891 p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!
```

and the list continues...

## Conclusion

All this to say that if you're going to do something inherently dirty, you might as well do it fast, and using sines isn't a good idea. You might as well multiply integers when possible (which isn't possible with JavaScript's representation of a number). Just "*use a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)*" and pay your respects to John von Neumann.

Answer (score -3):

I have written a function that returns a seeded random number, it uses Math.sin to have a long random number and uses the seed to pick numbers from that.

Use :

```
seedRandom("k9]:2@", 15)
```

it will return your seeded number
the first parameter is any string value ; your seed.
the second parameter is how many digits will return.

```
     function seedRandom(inputSeed, lengthOfNumber){

           var output = "";
           var seed = inputSeed.toString();
           var newSeed = 0;
           var characterArray = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','y','x','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','U','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')',' ','[','{',']','}','|',';',':',"'",',','<','.','>','/','?','`','~','-','_','=','+'];
           var longNum = "";
           var counter = 0;
           var accumulator = 0;

           for(var i = 0; i < seed.length; i++){
                var a = seed.length - (i+1);
                for(var x = 0; x < characterArray.length; x++){
                     var tempX = x.toString();
                     var lastDigit = tempX.charAt(tempX.length-1);
                     var xOutput = parseInt(lastDigit);
                     addToSeed(characterArray[x], xOutput, a, i); 
                }                  
           }

                function addToSeed(character, value, a, i){
                     if(seed.charAt(i) === character){newSeed = newSeed + value * Math.pow(10, a)}
                }
                newSeed = newSeed.toString();

                var copy = newSeed;
           for(var i=0; i<lengthOfNumber*9; i++){
                newSeed = newSeed + copy;
                var x = Math.sin(20982+(i)) * 10000;
                var y = Math.floor((x - Math.floor(x))*10);
                longNum = longNum + y.toString()
           }

           for(var i=0; i<lengthOfNumber; i++){
                output = output + longNum.charAt(accumulator);
                counter++;
                accumulator = accumulator + parseInt(newSeed.charAt(counter));
           }
           return(output)
      }
```

Comment: The sequences of numbers produced by this don't really approximate the properties of sequences of random numbers. Generate 15 numbers with it and the resulting string almost always begins with a 7 for nearly any key, for example.

Answer (score -4):

A simple approach for a fixed seed:

```
function fixedrandom(p){
    const seed = 43758.5453123;
    return (Math.abs(Math.sin(p)) * seed)%1;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

In PHP, there is function `srand(seed)` which generate fixed random value for particular seed.
But, in JS, there is no such inbuilt function.

However, we can write simple and short function.

*Step **1***: Choose some **Seed** (Fix Number). 
`var seed = 100;` 
Number should be Positive Integer and greater than 1, further explanation in *Step 2*.

*Step **2***: Perform **Math.sin()** function on **Seed**, it will give *sin value* of that number. Store this value in *variable x*.

```
var x; 
x = Math.sin(seed); // Will Return Fractional Value between -1 & 1 (ex. 0.4059..)
```

**sin()** method returns a Fractional value between -1 and 1.
And we don't need Negative value, therefore, in first step choose number greater than 1.

*Step **3***: Returned Value is a Fractional value between -1 and 1. 
So mulitply this value with 10 for making it more than 1.

```
x = x * 10; // 10 for Single Digit Number
```

*Step **4***: Multiply the value with 10 for additional digits

```
x = x * 10; // Will Give value between 10 and 99 OR
x = x * 100; // Will Give value between 100 and 999
```

Multiply as per requirement of digits.

The result will be in decimal.

*Step **5***: Remove value after Decimal Point by Math's Round (**Math.round()**) Method.

```
x = Math.round(x); // This will give Integer Value.
```

*Step **6***: Turn Negative Values into Positive (if any) by **Math.abs** method

```
x = Math.abs(x); // Convert Negative Values into Positive(if any)
```

*Explanation End.*
**Final Code**

```
var seed = 111; // Any Number greater than 1
var digit = 10 // 1 => single digit, 10 => 2 Digits, 100 => 3 Digits and so. (Multiple of 10) 

var x; // Initialize the Value to store the result
x = Math.sin(seed); // Perform Mathematical Sin Method on Seed.
x = x * 10; // Convert that number into integer
x = x * digit; // Number of Digits to be included
x = Math.round(x); // Remove Decimals
x = Math.abs(x); // Convert Negative Number into Positive
```

**Clean and Optimized Functional Code**

```
function random_seed(seed, digit = 1) {
    var x = Math.abs(Math.round(Math.sin(seed++) * 10 * digit));
    return x;
}
```

*Then Call this function using*
`random_seed(any_number, number_of_digits)`
**any_number** is must and should be greater than 1.
**number_of_digits** is optional parameter and if nothing passed, 1 Digit will return.

```
random_seed(555); // 1 Digit
random_seed(234, 1); // 1 Digit
random_seed(7895656, 1000); // 4 Digit
```

Comment: This function is biased as abs(Math.sin(random_number)) is itself a function biased around the point where slope of sin function is zero. Here's the code that can be run in js console for experiment: (https://pastebin.com/kJyHaQYY)

Answer (score -12):

For a number between 0 and 100.

```
Number.parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))
```

Comment: The question is about seeding `Math.random` such that whenever `Math.random` is seeded with the same seed, it will produce the same successive series of random numbers. This question is not, per say, about the actual usage/demonstration of `Math.random`.