# SQLite - ORDER BY RAND()

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sqlite, random-access

In MySQL I can use the RAND() function, is there any alternative in SQLite 3?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171578/seeding-sqlite-random

Answer (score 57, accepted):

using [random()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html):

```
SELECT foo FROM bar
  WHERE id >= (abs(random()) % (SELECT max(id) FROM bar))
  LIMIT 1;
```

---

**EDIT (by QOP):** Since the docs on [SQLite Autoincrement](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)ed columns states that:

> The normal ROWID selection algorithm described above *will generate
>   monotonically increasing unique ROWIDs* as long as you never use the
>   maximum ROWID value and you never delete the entry in the table with
>   the largest ROWID. **If you ever delete rows, then ROWIDs from
>   previously deleted rows might be reused when creating new rows**.

The above is only true if you don't have a `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` column (it will still work fine with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` columns). Anyway, this should be more portable / reliable:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar
  WHERE _ROWID_ >= (abs(random()) % (SELECT max(_ROWID_) FROM bar))
LIMIT 1;
```

`ROWID`, `_ROWID_` and `OID` are all aliases for the SQLite internal row id.

Comment: +1, This is way faster than the other options provided that id is index.

Comment: Yes this solution is faster, but assumes id starts at 1 and has no gaps.  Otherwise rows that follow gaps are "randomly" chosen more frequently than other rows.

Comment: Also the lowest ID will almost never be selected.

Comment: Wow, my query went from >300ms to 1ms!

Comment: Very good soluce to ge ONLY 1 row randomly, but doesn't work well with a limit bigger than 1 :/
Indeed, I made a test with only 4 inputs im my DDB and a limit of 5 => sometime I have 3 results, sometime 4 results...
I think there will be a better random with bigger DDB, but not for the little one.

Comment: This seems to select one row from the table at random, without trying to randomize the order; whereas the question title is about ORDER BY. In other words this answer doesn't answer the question. Yet it's highly voted and accepted. What gives?

Comment: Agree. This was at least an order of magnitude faster than 4-5 other queries I found on the web.

Answer (score 179):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: And for the record the limit doesn't have to be 1 if you want to order the entire table randomly and access all of the rows in that random order.

Comment: This will also work if you have a complex WHERE clause and want a random row from that filtered list. The accepted answer does not support that easily.

Comment: And One More this there is no duplicate row returned in Result, This is what I need (y)

Comment: why I use it has this message of wrong information:1st ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set

Answer (score 48):

Solved:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I disagree. We have two bits of info here now, how to select a single record randomly,how to list all the records randomly. I have never needed to do either, but if I do, now I know how. I also know that MySQL does it different to SQLlite. A super technical question would be more impressive, but less useful.

Comment: My first thought was that there wasn't any function to order results randomly, or if there was such a feature / function it would be considerable more obscure - that's what happens with SQLite triggers for instance.

Answer (score 34):

**For a much better performance use this in SQLite:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT x)
```

This is also applicable to MySQL. This runs faster because **SQL engines first load projected fields of rows to memory then sort them**, here we just load and random sort the id field of rows, then we get X of them, and find the whole rows of these X ids which is by default indexed.

Comment: +1. In my environment this is ~30 times faster compared to `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1`, and still gives true random w/o any requirements to table schema.

Comment: Seems the best answer to retrieve 200 results

Answer (score -1):

The goal is to get random results (Infinite Scroll) while being able to SQL paginate the results (`LIMIT a,b`), which needs a predictible outcome (pseudorandom aka PRNG).

`SIN(id + seed)` seems a great alternative to `RANDOM(seed)`.

Please consider this demo entirely written in JS that simulates an `ORDER BY` clause using a `SIN(id + seed)` scoring :

```js
// Inspired by:
// https://www.sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/e2216583a4
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/24511461/7776828

// Simulate N autoincrement stable ids 
// (Avoid rowid which is unstable)
const max = 20;
const a = Array();
for (let id = 0; id < max; ++id) {
  a.push({id});
}
console.log(a);

// Order the results by random
const orderByRandom = ({a, seed}) => {
  // For each result, 
  // Use sin(id + seed) to get a stable random score
  const randomScored = a.map(x => { 
    return { ...x, score: Math.sin(x.id + seed) }
  });
  // Sort by the random score
  randomScored.sort((a,b) => a.score - b.score);
  return randomScored;
}

// Used for generating the seed
const random = () => 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - 1);

let seed;

seed = random(); // seed #1
console.log(orderByRandom({a, seed})); 
console.log(orderByRandom({a, seed})); // Stable, can paginate

seed = random(); // seed #2
console.log(orderByRandom({a, seed})); // New order because new seed
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated to the latest version of sqlite3 in Node.js (it includes the math functions) and this approach worked.