# Seeding SQLite RANDOM()

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, random, seeding

Does SQLite support seeding the **[`RANDOM()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#random)** function the same way MySQL does with **[`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)**?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND(" . date('Ymd') . ") LIMIT 1;";
```

**From the MySQL Manual about `RAND(N)`:**

> If a constant integer argument N is
>   specified, it is used as the seed
>   value, which produces a repeatable
>   sequence of column values. In the
>   following example, note that the
>   sequences of values produced by
>   RAND(3) is the same both places where
>   it occurs.

If not, is there any way to archive the same effect using only one query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need a pseudo-random order, you can do something like this (PHP):

```
$seed = md5(mt_rand());
$prng = ('0.' . str_replace(['0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['7', '3', '1', '5', '9', '8', '4'], $seed )) * 1;
$query = 'SELECT id, name FROM table ORDER BY (substr(id * ' . $prng . ', length(id) + 2))';
```

Plus, you can set $seed to the predefined value and always get same results.

I've learned this trick from my colleague http://steamcooker.blogspot.com/

Comment: Can you please explain this solution?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't scale very well for large tables.

Comment: Luda, sorry for not answering in time. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24511461/296520 is a good explanation of what's going on there.

Comment: Is this missing a trailing bracket? I've got ORDER BY (substr(....)

Comment: @JCx Indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the [`sqlite3_randomness()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/randomness.html) function:

> SQLite contains a high-quality pseudo-random number generator (PRNG) used to select random ROWIDs when inserting new records into a table that already uses the largest possible ROWID. **The PRNG is also used for the build-in random() and randomblob() SQL functions.**
>
> ...
>
> The first time this routine is invoked (either internally or by the application) the PRNG is **seeded using randomness obtained from the xRandomness method of the default sqlite3_vfs object**. On all subsequent invocations, the pseudo-randomness is generated internally and without recourse to the sqlite3_vfs xRandomness method.

Looking at the source of this `xRandomness` method, you can see that it reads from `/dev/urandom` on Unix. On Windows, it just returns the return values of some time functions. So it seems that your only option is to start hacking on the SQLite source code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of [@jankkhvej](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2469943/3142139)
I will do a modification  to the code to control generating PRNG using a predefined seed (integer-32 bit number) and document the code.

Actually the seed in PHP is defined using the function [mt_srand($seed)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php)

```
//define seed (modify it as needed), so you can get the same series every time you run the code.
$seed=123456789;
//mt_srand — Seeds the Mersenne Twister Random Number Generator
mt_srand($seed);

//compute hash md5 for mt_rand()
$md5 = md5(mt_rand());
//use md5 to get a decimal number by replacing the hex-decimal chars abcef by numeric values, then prefix the result with "0."
$prng = ('0.' . str_replace(['0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['7', '3', '1', '5', '9', '8', '4'], $md5 )) * 1;

//sqlite is using rowid, a unique number for row. If you defined a primary key, it can be rowid. 
//multiply rowid by $prng , and extract only the fraction part using substr function
//e.g 1.0519815151568 will be   0519815151568
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM table ORDER BY (substr(rowid * $prng , length(rowid) + 2))";
```

Try [onlin demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/dd2fd)

output

```
seed= 1234567890
mt_rand= 1328851649
MD5 hash= 1abfd768d39fc907c278ec2cb8ae809b
prng= 0.1314976893946
SQLite version 3.7.17
Selecting 3 random rows of 10, with PRNG: 0.1314976893946
Id  name    rowid*prng         random
8   p_8     1.0519815151568    0519815151568
1   p_1     0.1314976893946    1314976893946
10  p_10    1.314976893946     14976893946
```

I provided an alternative solution to generate PNRG , you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76007175/3142139)