# SQLite - select random datetime in range

Tags: sql, random, sqlite

Im not familiar with SQLite. Can someone help me with generating random datetime value?

I tried to start with this (its for MS-SQL):

```
select dateadd(
               millisecond, 
               cast(86400000 * RAND() as int), 
               convert(time, '00:00')
               );
```

but sqlite returns error: `invalid column millisecond`.

I need something, that allows to generate random datetime with specified minimum and maximum date, but **for now I think just need to know how to convert number to date**.

Im using SQLite version 3.7.15.1.

Comment: Please review this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171578/seeding-sqlite-random

Comment: Your syntax is SQL Server, not SQLite.  What database are you using?

Comment: Are there any limits on the range you want for this random date?  Can it be 1000 years from now as well?

Comment: @PinnyM in this case i need ranges from 10 hours to few days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`random()` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#random) generates random 64-bit integers.
The [`strftime()` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) with the `'%s'` parameter converts a date/time string into the number of seconds since 1970.
The [`datetime()` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) with the `'unixepoch'` modifier converts a number of seconds into a date/time string.

To convert the random integer into the desired range of seconds, use the modulo operator (`%`) with the difference in seconds between the min/max dates as range, and add that to the start date.
For example, the following will generate a random timestamp in Jan 2000:

```
SELECT datetime(strftime('%s', '2000-01-01 00:00:00') +
                abs(random() % (strftime('%s', '2000-01-31 23:59:59') -
                                strftime('%s', '2000-01-01 00:00:00'))
                   ),
                'unixepoch');
```