# Sqlite query change random number every minute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, random

`ROR Active Record`, there is `Sqlite` query, which is returning rows ordered by random number. Is it possible to change the random number one time per minute? So the query result is the same during 60 seconds (assuming that database is not modified).

`@topics = Topic.order('id + abs(random()%101) DESC').limit(10`)

Comment: From seeing [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24394275/1544012) I don't think that is possible under sqlite, as **sqlite does not support seeding** the random number generator. If you switched to MySQL, it should be possible to simply seed the `rand()` with a pseudo-random number that changes every minute.

Comment: the solution has been applied to cache query result using Rails cache for one minute: 

`Rails.cache.fetch("cache_key", expires_in: 1.minutes) do ....... whatever data query here ........... end`