# How to set random seed in sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func.random() in python?

Tags: python, random, sqlalchemy

I would like to set a random seed when shuffling a sqlalchmy query result using order_by to get always the same query result:

```
my_query.order_by(func.random())
```

I could not find how to do it in the documentation. I tried it with

```
my_query.order_by(func.random(random_seed=1))
my_query.order_by(func.random(random_state=1))
```

but both didn't work.
Thank you in advance for any idea/hint!

All best,
Lea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy `func` object just renders functions in SQL.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import func
>>> print(func.random())
random()
```

In some cases (including this one), it will render a different underlying function on different database backends, e.g. on MySQL:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
>>> print(func.random().compile(dialect=mysql.dialect()))
rand()
```

This means that the database you're using is what produces the random number, and so you must call a database specific function to set the seed, e.g. on PostgreSQL you use [`setseed`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-RANDOM-TABLE), which is called in the same way as other SQL functions:

```
>>> func.setseed(0.123...)
```

Comment: I'm using a simple sqllite data base. I tried to use the setseed command but it does not work. Any idea how to do it in sqllite? The docs don't seem to address this issue.

Comment: The SQLAlchemy part of your question has been answered, but really you're asking a database question. It's not possible on SQLite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256258/order-by-random-with-seed-in-sqlite