# Python - most efficient way to select a random message according to a type

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, random

I have some (hundreds of) messages with a type:

```
Type Message
1    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
1    Maecenas eu risus a arcu rutrum vehicula vel in neque.
1    Curabitur ante sapien, cursus nec diam non, porttitor sagittis leo.
2    Nunc et nisi nec ligula placerat accumsan.
2    In lacinia, neque rutrum aliquet luctus, odio ligula accumsan risus.
3    ...
3    ...
...  ...
```

I want to select a random message from type 1 messages, or type 2 messages, etc. I want to build an efficient way. So my questions are:

How should i store these messages? With a list, dictionary, txt or DB table (i'm also using Django). Messages will be static. I won't change or edit them regularly. Buy maybe in the future i'll need to use translations for other languages.

How can i select a RANDOM message according to type? i.e. "a random message with type 1".

Thanks all,

Comment: This sounds exactly like [fortune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_%28Unix%29) to me.  That usually stores the messages in separate files, one per "type" and separated with `%` lines.

Comment: Yes, in also some MUD games, social messages are stored in plain txt files and seperated by a character. But is it suitable to my situation. Fortune messages are old, MUD is also old. Maybe now we have different options :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your messages in a Django model, then select your messages using the [random order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
from django.db import models    


class Message(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    message_text = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    @classmethod
    def random_by_type(cls, type_number):
        return cls.objects.filter(type=type_number).order_by('?').first()
```

I've made it a class method, so you can pick a random message with:

```
random_message = Message.random_by_type(1)
```

You can certainly do this with a static setup too:

```
import random

messages = {
    1: ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        'Maecenas eu risus a arcu rutrum vehicula vel in neque.'
        'Curabitur ante sapien, cursus nec diam non, porttitor sagittis leo.',
    ],
    2: ['Nunc et nisi nec ligula placerat accumsan.',
        'In lacinia, neque rutrum aliquet luctus, odio ligula accumsan risus.',
    ],
    3: ['....'],
    # ...
}

def random_by_type(type_number):
    return random.choice(messages[type_number])
```

but why ignore the possibility to use the Django admin interface to manage the messages?

Comment: "Note: order_by('?') queries may be expensive and slow, depending on the database backend you’re using." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: In my opinion, order_by(?) would be slower and expensive. I'll work with static messages, do i need a db table?

Comment: @Jai: For most databases there is an [efficient random-row selection option available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql). Even [sqlite supports it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253561/sqlite-order-by-rand).

Comment: Actually i loved your second suggestion.

I dont ignore Django. But for really static messages with a type option only, i dont want to work with db queries, to optimize them etc.

Comment: @Jai: sure, then just use the dictionary+list option. For a few hundred such messages that is going to be the fastest option, the only downside is that you cannot manage the messages from the admin interface, really.

Comment: @Pieters, thanks for suggesting two options and discussing them.