# How to create random/shuffle filter without infinite digest loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I would want to achieve the following:

- To be able to show image from array in random order.

To solve this, I decided to create a filter :

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app. filter('randomizer', randomizer);


 function randomizer() {

        return function (collection, defaultValue) {

            var result = defaultValue;

            if (!!collection) {
                if (Array.isArray(collection) && collection.length === 1) {
                    result = collection[0] || defaultValue;
                } else if (!Array.isArray(collection)) {
                    result = collection || defaultValue;
                } else {
                    // randomize here please
                    var idx = parseInt(((Math.random()) * collection.length));
                    result = collection[idx] || defaultValue;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Now in template, I am calling as:

```
<div class="masonry-pin masonry-brick" ng-repeat="p in vm.list | orderBy: 'updatedAt':true">

     <img ng-src="{{vm.baseUrl + 'documents/view/' + ( p.documents | randomizer:{id: 'notfound'}:p.id).id }}">

</div>
```

However, I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: [NG-Modular Error] [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest()
>   iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:
>   [[{"msg":"fn:
>   expressionInputsWatch","newVal":"http://localhost:3002/documents/view/158","oldVal":"http://localhost:3002/documents/view/159"},{"msg":"fn:

After doing some research, I found that it is do with value changes, but where I am changing my values.

Now I can understand that some how it might be the scope is changing. However, what I have noticed that even if I have a simple filter like this: {{p.documents | console}}

and the console filter just takes an array and print in the console.

Now when I have 10 objects in the list, It is calling filter 30 times.

Here is how the console filter is, but for 10 items it is calling 66 times.

Why ??

```
app.filter('console', pipeConsole);

function pipeConsole() {


        return function (value, o) {
            print(value);
            print(o);
            print(count);

        }

        function print(o) {
            if (!!o) {
                console.log(o);
            }
            else if (o === null) {
                console.warn(o);
            }
        }
    };
```

Here I am not even returning different values... (if I go with the logic explained here - [Angular: infinite digest loop in filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066919/angular-infinite-digest-loop-in-filter))

Even if it is not a filter,then also it is causing this problem

Now that I have created a service function, and I am having this problem.

```
 <img ng-src="{{vm.baseUrl + 'documents/view/' + vm.random( p.documents , {id: 'notfound'}).id }}">


vm.random = function (a, s) {

            return utility.randomizer(a, s);
        };
```

So what is the solution??

Comment: you are directly playing with the `collection` which is scope variable, any change in `collection` firing digest cycle & the apparently filter is getting fired..which is causing `10 $digest() iterations reached` this issue..I'd suggest you take a copy of `collection` first using `angular.copy` & play with it and then assign back to result when you are done

Comment: Thanks @pankajparkar however I am not doing any modifications. Also, I have updated my question as I am also using ngrepeat statement.

Comment: Also changed my filter and added the following line var collection = angular.copy(col);
and using copy as suggested. However the result is same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular: infinite digest loop in filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066919/angular-infinite-digest-loop-in-filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the infinite digest, you need to wrap your filter in a `memoize` function. The best way to solve your problem is to install `knuth-shuffle` and `lodash` from `npm`, then use whatever module system you like to create the filter. This example is with CommonJS/browserify.

```
var memoize = require('lodash/function/memoize');
var shuffle = require('knuth-shuffle');

app.filter('shuffle', function() {
  return memoize(shuffle);
});
```

When creating filters this way, you may have a problem if an empty value is passed to the `shuffle` function. In that case, just add a check:

```
app.filter('shuffle', function() {
  return memoize(function(input) {
    if (input === undefined) { return; }
    return shuffle.apply(null, arguments);
  });
});
```

You can learn more about the infinite digest problem from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25315679/1435655).

To re-shuffle the list, you can pass an arbitrary $scope property to the filter, then change that property when you want to re-shuffle. Either incrementing a number or using `Math.random()` are a good way to do this. This works because the result is cached according to the arguments passed, so passing an otherwise useless argument produces a new result.

```
myList | shuffle:whatever
```

```
$scope.whatever = 0;
$scope.reshuffle = function() {
  ++$scope.whatever;
  // OR
  $scope.whatever = Math.random();
};
```

Comment: thank you so much and now I understand how the binding reacts. I still wonder why the logic is written in ng that checks the value of an object so many times, especially when it is not changing. There must be a way to tell in ng to not to watch or something. Btw,_.memoize has fixed the problem.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it has solved the error that I have reported. hwver, I cannot randomize then because it is cached. either I change on load or probably I can use memoizedFunc.cache to clear!

Comment: @codebased oh, I forgot to mention that! You should be able to just pass an arbitrary $scope property and change it when you want to refilter. I updated my answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: ahh ha! Thank you once again.