# Set `background-color` property randomly once

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a blog theme for [Anchor CMS](http://www.anchorcms.com) and I have a question regarding randomly assigning background colors to divs.

I have a working script which assigns a color randomly to each div with the `post` class. What I'd like to know is if I can set the color once - say, when the post is published - and have it persist on each page load rather than resetting.

Here's my function:

```
$(".post").each(function randomColor() {
        var color = "#"+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
        $(this).css("background-color", color)
      })
```

I'm thinking that I could create an array in the blog registry using PHP and pass values into it based on the post ID, but I don't want to overcomplicate the process if there's a simpler method.

A nice extension, but not necessary, would be to carry that color over to the post itself when the user visits it.

Any thoughts?

**Edit** - You can see my [demo site](http://dev.brianbennett.org/anchor) to get an idea of what the theme looks like. The random color addition is *not* implemented there as of right now.

Comment: how unique shoud the color be?

Comment: You could hash the color based on the content of the post, or seed your rng based on the time of the post. The possibilities are endless.

Comment: Even if you created the array you would have to store it as well. If you already have a database you could store it there. However if you are storing colors that are going to be used for ever why not just pick the colors and hard code them

Comment: Or you could just do a bunch of `:nth-child(387)` in a giant static CSS file with pre-selected random colors.

Comment: do you have any track of the timestamp the post was published?

Comment: I was going to suggest the hash and random seed ideas as well. Unfortunately you can't seed javascript's native rng - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/javascript-random-seeds

Comment: @amphetamachine I'm not too familiar with hashing, so I'll have to look into that. It's a pretty minimal theme, so there isn't much to pull from.

Comment: @Onheiron there is a PHP function for the article timestamp, so yes, I can get that info. How would you use it?

Comment: what about the ID? do they have a sequential post id?

Comment: Yeah, it's sequential and has a PHP call as well, so I can append something to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some considerations at first:

1. not all colours are worth using: all possible colours are a lot, but not all of them would look nice in the page (think at all the very dark ones, shades of grey etc.).
2. even if you keep a certain brightness to them colours, it'd be a good idea to keep them distinguishable (e.g. 00FF00 and 00FE00 are very alike and one won't even notice)
3. you need to create a subset of "worthy" colours. Let's say you want 25 different colours (which I think is fair given point 1 and 2). So 3 different picks for each RGB which is 3^3 = 27 minus two because when all three are at max and when all three are at min it's gonna be grey (not nice).
4. so you need a parameter ranging from 1 to 25 sufficiently random among all posts OR a sequential parameter (an auto-incremental ID?) so that the whole set of possible colours is used before starting over again.

---

```
postID = /* get your post ID as int */

/* gets a number between 1 and 25 from your post ID */
colourID = (postID % 25) + 1 

/* this tells which "step" to use for each colour */
/* i.e. 20 in base 3 is "202" -> (2*9 + 0*3 + 2*1) = 18 + 2 = 20 */
/* so will keep "step 2" for red, "step 0" for green and "step 2" for blue */
base3ColourID = colourID.toString(3) 

/* this always returns 3 digits */
/* base3ColourID is 1 if ID is 1, we need "001" to have the colour "steps" */
niceB3CID = ("000").substring(base3ColourID.length) + base3ColourID 

/* calculate the actual colours */
red = 65 + 70*(parseInt(niceB3CID.charAt(0)))
green = 65 + 70*(parseInt(niceB3CID.charAt(1)))
blue = 65 + 70*(parseInt(niceB3CID.charAt(2)))

$('.post').css('background-color', "rgb("+red+","+green+","+blue+")")
```

[HERE A FIDDLE IF YOU WANT TO PLAY WITH THEM COLOURS](http://jsfiddle.net/867m6jLg/4/)

**Edit**

edited colour ranges for better colours.

Comment: I like this, and I appreciate the explanation. I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to get the post ID programatically. Any pointers on that?

Comment: you mean how to get the postID from PHP variable to JS? If so in your post tag you can echo the id as an attribute like this `<div class="post" data-id="<? echo $postID; ?>">` and then in js `$('.post').each()` and `$(this).attr('data-id')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the day of the year (0 - 365) the post was published as the first value in an `hsl` color (0 - 360, you can pick a random number for the 5 days after 360).

I think using `hsl()` would be a much safer bet as well. You'll know you won't get something completely terrible and the colors will be sort of similar. Here's a small demo...

http://jsbin.com/kagube/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Note, There may be "bug" at

`(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)`

where , occasionally , the `length` of the string generated may be `5` , instead of `6` , resulting in an element without a `background-color` being applied to the elements' `style` ; i.e.g.,

```
var arr = [], res = []; 
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  arr.push((Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16));
};

$.each(arr, function(k, v) {
  if (v.length < 6) {
    res.push(v);
  }
});

console.log(res.length);
```

a quick-fix solution is included within piece below

Try

html

```
<!-- 
     given each "inner-container" element 
     within `.post` "outer-container"
     has some form of `unique-id` -->
<div class="post">
    <span id="a"></span>
    <span id="b"></span>
    <span id="c"></span>
    <span id="d"></span>
    <span id="e"></span>
    <span id="f"></span>
    <span id="g"></span>
    <span id="h"></span>
</div>
```

js

```
// this piece could actually be run when the "post" ,
// or element , is generated , instead of each occasion
// the document is loaded .
// the `colors` array could be stored at server , 
// as `json` object ,e.g., "colors.json", or other preferred format ,
// updating when new "post" is created / generated .
// the array generated could contain two members :
// the unique "id" of the "post" , and the color
// associated with that `unique-id`
// the data could then be posted to server
// which updates `colors.json` file with
// new entries
var colors = [];
    $(".post span").each(function(i, el) {
        // `bug` : occasionally returns string having 
        // `length` of `5` , instead of `6`
        var r = ((Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16));
        // _quickix_ : check `length` of `r` string ,
        // if `< 6` , generate random "number" between 0-9 ,
        // concat to `r`
        r = r.length < 6 ? r + (1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)) : r;
        var color = "#" + r ;

        // apply `color` to `background-color` , here ,
        // if desired
        // $(el).css("background-color", color);

        // push `unique-id , color` pair to `colors` array
        colors.push([el.id, color]);

        // optional , `POST` new `colors` array to server ,
        // adding new entry to `colors.json` ,
        // unique for each `unique-id`
        // $.post("colors.php", {"data" : colors});
      });

// when loading "template" of `html` `.post` "posts" ,
// having unique id's , or , being generated dynamically
// and given `unique-id`'s , apply `color` to each element
// based on `unique-id` and `color` generated for it
// when created

// optional : `$.getJSON("colors.json", function(colors) {});`
// having `$.each()` function at `complete` callback 
// reassembly `colors` associated with `unique-id`'s
$.each(colors, function(k, v) {
   $(".post span[id="+v[0]+"]").css("background-color", v[1])
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/f895bh53/