# Creating large array/data from seed/key

Tags: javascript, node.js, key, procedural-generation, random-seed

firstly the language Im writing in is node (javascript) but really Im looking for the computer science behind it, and how to actually do it, not just the code.

Basically what I have is a 2,000 x 2,000 two dimensional array (what I mean by that is that every entry in the 2,000 entry long array has its own 2,000 entries). Inside this array I have values 0, 1, 2 3, etc. They are spaced out different, with different rarities as to how common each appears. What I want to do is generate this array based on a key, idc how long  the key/seed is, just a reasonable length that can get the job done. I want the same key to generate the same array if its the same key and a different one if its a different key. Basically take a key and generate longer data from it but for no recognizable patterns to appear in this data.

My thoughts on this is to have a key that is a decimal of some sort I multiply against a bunch of constants to get a location in the array, but tbh I really have no Idea where to start. Essentially its like how minecraft takes a seed and turns it into map and the same seed will again generate an identical map.

Comment: could you insert an example to illustrate your need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any random number generator (RNG) that can be seeded will give the same series of random values for a given seed & should have no determinable pattern. Unfortunately, [the default RND for javascript is not seedable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random); as per this SE post, [you will need to write your own or use a someone else's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/javascript-random-seeds).

Once you have a seedable RNG, for each entry, first get a random value & then convert the random value into the desired output value. There's a number of different ways to do the conversion; if you only have a few, I would do something like this (assumes random_value is between 0 & 1):

```
if(rand_value <= 70){
  output_value = 1;
}
else if(rand_value <= 90){
  output_value = 2;
}
else if(rand_value <= 97){
  output_value = 3;
}
else {
  output_value = 4
}
```

This gives a 70%, 20%, 7% & 3% to get a 1,2,3 or 4 respectively; adjust the values as needed. Note: if you have many output values you should edit your question to reflect this, as there are cleaner ways to solve this than a giant if else block.

Comment: Thank you, I was confused as to what a seeded random number generator was but now I realize it's exactly what I need