# Random color from array on website

Tags: javascript, html, css

Pretty new to code. Having some trouble implementing some code to randomize the **background color** of part of my website to change based on an array.
Found this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ["#4ECDC4","#FF6B6B","#313638","#FFE66D"];                
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
  $(‘#u97’, ‘#u379’).css("background-color", colors[rand]);
});
```

The "#u97, #u379" are the divs that I want to change the background color of. I insert the code in the header with a "script" tag but nothing happens. There is also a master CSS file that the divs get the color from, could that be interfering with something?

Comment: First of all, the selectors are in one string with no comma. Second of all, those quotes look awfully strange...

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your code? Because that code uses it (`$(document).ready`). If not, you can either include it or look for a pure JavaScript code.

Comment: I am not even sure, again new at this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ["#4ECDC4","#FF6B6B","#313638","#FFE66D"];                
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
  $('#u97').css("background-color", colors[rand]);
  $('#u379').css("background-color", colors[rand]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't seem to function. It's supposed to choose a different color on each reload but it's not.

Comment: I think your rand is not seeded with something that is different every time. Your code would probably repeat the same sequence every time you load the page unless you seed it with something like a datetime for instance.

Comment: My mistake. please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/javascript-random-seeds

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ["#4ECDC4","#FF6B6B","#313638","#FFE66D"];                
  var rand = function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);        
  };
  
  $("#u97, #u379").each(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", colors[rand()]);
  });
});
```

```css
div {height: 50px; width: 50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="u97"></div><div id="u379"></div>
```