# What's the JS equivalent of Pythons Tensorflow tf.random.set_seed(123)?

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow

It's a shame they didn't just repeat the API, or at least didn't try to keep it as close as possible... So, what's the JS equivalent of `tf.random.set_seed(5)`? Thank you.

And no, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript) is not an answer for mine, I don't need to implement my own PRNG, I don't need "random seed" for my own purposes, I need to seed TensorFlow so it initializes my neural networks in a repeatable way.

Comment: You can’t seed Math.random() Read here for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seeding the random number generator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript)

Comment: Dan, no, you can seed if you implement your own generator, for example "Mersenne Twister" or even simpler LCG. Philip, it doesn't answer my question - I don't need to implement my own PRNG, I don't need it for my own purposes, I need to seed TensorFlow so it initializes my neural networks in a repeatable way.