# How can I create a seed-based randomizer that will allow me to skip to any step at anytime?

Tags: javascript, math, random, mathematical-optimization, random-seed

```
// imagine i have a seed based random number generator
const list = []
for ( let i = 0; i < 24; ++i ) {
  list.push( Math.randomIn( 0, 100 ) )
}
// it always outputs
[70, 58, 88, 80, 12, 91, 1, 21, 26, 61, 41, 83, 22, 29, 92, 87, 31, 16, 7, 39, 53, 31, 62, 55]

// however for my case, i need 8388608000000 values
// i would like to be able to have

getSeedBasedRNGByIndex( 2955246414062 )

// is there a way to skip ahead or go backward using a satisfyingly random seed based generator ?
```

In my cases, I have a need to quickly skip ahead in a seed based RNG.  It definitely helps if I can also go backwards as well

Edit: The question is not how to get a seed based random generator, the question is how to make one that allows me to jump to and from steps in its results

Comment: use an lfsr routine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seeding the random number generator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript)

Comment: Look up jumpable and leapable random number generators.