# Generate random 6 characters based on input

Tags: javascript, math

Generate random 6 characters based on input. Like I want to turn `1028797107357892628` into `j4w8p`. Or `102879708974181177` into `lg36k` but I want it to be consistant. Like whenever I feed `1028797107357892628` in, it should always spit out `j4w8p`. Is this possible? (Without a database if possible.) I know how to generate random 6 characters **but I dont know how to connect it with an input tbh.** I would appreciate any help, thanks.

```js
let rid = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);
```

Comment: You're probably looking for a "seed". These parameters are inputted into functions and decide what they output -- for example, a unix timestamp can be used as a seed.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript may be able to help you with this.

Comment: It's called hashing usually

Comment: it's called a PRNG, there's lots of them, some quite short in code length if needed. The built-in crypto hashing can also be used by chopping off 64 bit chunks, converting to an int, then calling `num.toString(36)` to get your alphabetical representation.

Comment: PRNG = pseudorandom number generator

Comment: Note that the Javascript [Number object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) has 15 - 17 digits of precision, and therefore treating `1028797107357892628` as a Number rather than String or BigInt results in a rounded value of `1028797107357892600`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, solved my issue.

Code:

```js
  let seed = Number(1028797089741811773)
  let rid = seed.toString(36).substring(0,6)
  console.log(rid)
```

Or:

```js
  let seed = Number(1028797089741811773)
  let rid = seed.toString(36).substring(6)
  console.log(rid)
```

Comment: The output is not 6 characters.  Would .substring(0,6) work better?

Comment: Yeah i noticed, but its not that important. I just estimated 6 would be nice, but 5 works too. But you are right, would be better like that.

Comment: Yet it is important as you specifically asked for 6 characters in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom hashing function a simple function to your code would be

```js
const seed = "1028797089741811773";

function customHash(str, outLen){
  //The 4 in the next regex needs to be the length of the seed divided by the desired hash lenght
  const regx = new RegExp(`.{1,${Math.floor(str.length / outLen)}}`, 'g')
  const splitted = str.match(regx);
  
 
  
  let out = "";
  for(const c of splitted){
    let ASCII = c % 126;
    if( ASCII < 33) ASCII = 33
  
   out += String.fromCharCode(ASCII)
  }

  return out.slice(0, outLen)
}


const output = customHash(seed, 6)

console.log(output)
```

Comment: This seems like a good start, but it outputs a variable length string. Is there a way to change this to output 6 characters per the question?

Comment: Will edit the answe

Comment: @Yogi Edited the answer, should work as expected now

Comment: up voted with revisions.

Answer (score 0):

It is called hashing, hashing is not random. In your example to get `rid`:

```
let rid = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);
```

Because it is **random**, it's impossible to be able to produce "consistant result" as you expect.

You need algorithm to produce a "random" consistant result.