# Using useEffect in React to change API request

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I am learning React hooks and made a project to display a random Pokemon name through https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#pokemon by calling a random Pokemon ID. I'm not quite sure how to trigger the `useEffect` to fetch after clicking on the button.

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


  function getNewPokemonId(pokemon){
  pokemon =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 1011);
  console.log(pokemon)
  return pokemon;
}

function App() {
  const [pokemon , setNewPokemon] = useState(1);


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("render");
    const pokemonID = getNewPokemonId()
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonID}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) =>
      setNewPokemon(json)
  );
  
  }, []);


  return (
    <main>
      <h1>
        Random Pokemon Generator
      </h1>
      <section>
        <button onClick={() => setNewPokemon(getNewPokemonId(pokemon))}>
          New Pokemon
        </button>
        <h3>{pokemon?.name}</h3>
      </section>

    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After clicking on the button I don't get a new Pokemon name instead it is blank.

Comment: at the end of the useEffect in the [], do this: [pokemon], then the useEffect will trigger every time that variable changes

Comment: State variables are the ones that modify the GUI once they are updated. While it is not obligatory, I suggest to use a prefix to differentiate state variables as st_variableName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sandbox with this app working:

#### Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-morning-tkwtpv

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function getNewPokemonId() {
  const pokemon = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1011);
  console.log(pokemon);
  return pokemon;
}

export default function App() {
  const [pokemon, setNewPokemon] = useState(1);

  const fetchPokemon = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${getNewPokemonId()}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setNewPokemon(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPokemon();
  }, []);

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    fetchPokemon();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Random Pokemon Generator</h1>
      <section>
        <button onClick={handleOnClick}>New Pokemon</button>
        <h3>{pokemon?.name}</h3>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope that this could help

Comment: this works perfectly thank you! Just so I understand it correctly can you explain how this `useEffect` is getting triggered in this case? Is it because we are calling that `fetchpokemon()` function?

Comment: Yes exactly, the useEffect will running one time with empty dependency array, so this fetchPokemon will be called one time and will update the state. So, when u click, the fetch will be called again with the clickHandler

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function to fetch the data for a Pokemon by id and call it on mount and in the click event handler.

```
function App() {
  const [pokemon, setNewPokemon] = useState();
  const getPokemon = id => fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`).then(res => res.json()).then(d => setNewPokemon(d));
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("render");
    getPokemon(getNewPokemonId());
  }, []);

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Random Pokemon Generator</h1>
      <section>
        <button onClick={() => getPokemon(getNewPokemonId())}>
          New Pokemon
        </button>
        <h3>{pokemon?.name}</h3>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

having `[]` at the end of the useEffect will mean it will only trigger once at the start of the page load.
having this: `[pokemon]` will make the useEffect run every time the variable changes.

Comment: I have tried this previously and this will just create an infinite loop since the `pokemon` will never stop changing.

Answer (score 0):

It' not fool-proof, but it's a start. You should store the Pokémon data into the state, not the ID. Make sure you properly set the state as well.

### Note

If you notice, the IDs jump from 1010 to 10001.

So the random range should technically be: 1-1010, 10001-10271.

---

## Example

Here is an basic working example of a Pokémon randomizer. It's fairly responsive.

```js
const { useCallback, useEffect, useState } = React;

// Better PRNG than Math.random
// Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593316/1762224
const mulberry32 = (seed) =>
  () => {
    let t = seed += 0x6D2B79F5;
    t = Math.imul(t ^ t >>> 15, t | 1);
    t ^= t + Math.imul(t ^ t >>> 7, t | 61);
    return ((t ^ t >>> 14) >>> 0) / 4294967296;
  }

const rand = mulberry32(performance.now()); // Seeded with current time

const randomInt = (min, max) => Math.floor(rand() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

const toTitleCase = (str = '') =>
  str.replace(/\w\S*/g, (txt) =>
    txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase());

// Refer to: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=2000
const ranges = [[1, 1010], [10001, 10271]]; // Distribution: (1010, 271)

const getRandomId = () => {
  const which = randomInt(1, 5);
  const range = ranges[which === 5 ? 1 : 0]; // 20% for range #2
  return randomInt(...range);
};

const apiBaseUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2';

const App = () => {
  const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState({ id: 0, name: '', sprites: [] });
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errorText, setErrorText] = useState('');
  
  const randomize = useCallback(() => {
    setErrorText('');
    setLoading(true);
    const randId = getRandomId();
    fetch(`${apiBaseUrl}/pokemon/${randId}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setPokemonData(data);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setErrorText(`Pokemon with ID of ${randId} not found!`);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    randomize();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Random Pokemon Generator</h1>
      <section>
        <button disabled={loading} onClick={randomize}>New Pokemon</button>
        {errorText !== '' && <p style={{color:'red'}}>{errorText}</p>}
        <h3>[{pokemonData.id}] {toTitleCase(pokemonData.name)}</h3>
        <img src={pokemonData.sprites.front_default} />
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```