# Is xoshiro128** pseudorandom number generator reversible?

Tags: javascript, random

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593316) answer mentions the xoshiro128** algorithm and provides a JavaScript implementation.

Question: Is it possible to derive the seed if you know the first random number produced by this generator?

Comment: With a single number? No. Just no.

Comment: So this is a security property it has by design, right? Seed is intentionally hard to derive by looking at produced numbers?

Comment: Yes. If the seed were easily derived them any cryptographic algorithm which uses the pseudo-random number generator would also be easy to break.

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to add an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: @JesseSealand: No cryptographic algorithm implementation should use this PRNG. It doesn't have any security properties by design.

Comment: To clarify, my comment was about PRNGs in general and not this specific one, if there was any confusion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to derive a seed given a single value. There is also no guarantee that you can derive a seed given any number of consecutive values. Even if you pre computed every possible seed value in advance its extremely unlikely that you will find only one sequence thats starts with whatever that first value is.

Comment: Your first sentence is correct, but I believe you're mistaken about the rest. Xoshiro128** is a deterministic algorithm, so it's not a question of likelihood. Every seed produces a specific sequence, it's only a question of how long a subsequence is needed to uniquely determine the 128 bit state. If at any point you can determine the state, the entire sequence is predictable with certainty.

Comment: Yes but you can't gaurantee that the first value in every possible solution is unique without calculating the entire solution space. Of course it's deterministic. That's why it's called pseudo random.

Comment: Agreed, which is why I said your first sentence is correct. However, with a state space of 128 bits you should be able to uniquely identify the state with very few observations. Mersenne Twister, which has a state space of 19937 bits, can be cracked after observing 623 32-bit values. I haven't seen cracking code for Xoshiro128**, but by extension you should be able to nail it after 4 32-bit observations.

Answer (score 3):

The xoshiro generators are not cryptographically secure, so they can be broken, given a sufficient number of outputs. They will be secure against a single output number, but not for some larger number.

To the [xoshiro](https://prng.di.unimi.it) website says that the xoshiro256++/xoshiro256** are all-purpose generators, but are not cryptographically secure.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it would be ok to use it for a non-serious lottery where at most $100 is at stake, and a sequence of 100 values will be revealed?

Comment: Are you legally liable, or is this just between friends? It is not that difficult to find a [cryptographically secure RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator), though I am not sure about how they work with Javascript. The original arc4random (using RC4) is probably easiest to implement in Javascript, but has definite weaknesses due to using RC4.

Comment: Just between friends

Comment: I think the webcrypto API has a CSPRNG.

Comment: Yes there's crypto.getRandomValues(), but you can't set a custom seed. I want to be able to reveal the seed after the game ends, so that players can verify that I didn't made up the random values.

Comment: @RomanPominov: Ah, I see, that makes sense. I think Rossum's rc4 suggestion is a winner then.