Select a random number for a certain seed, being sure the previous seed doesn't select the same random number
Say I have a random number generator which takes a seed and gives a number between 1 and 10.
Say I have a seed '100'. This would generate a random number '4'. How would I be sure that this number isn't the same as generated with seed '99'?
At first this seems a simple problem: check seed '99' and if the random numbers are the same, find a different number.
But this poses the big problem: what if seed '98' also had the same number? Seed '99' would be different. So, at seed '100' it wouldn't be sufficient to only check seed '99'. You would also need to check '98', '97', '96', etcetera.
How can I make a random generator that is sure that: the number generated is different from the number of the previous seed? (with previous I mean the integer before the current seed)
PS: setting a lower bound for the seed and brute forcing from seed '0' to seed '100' would work here, but the efficiency of this is low, especially with higher number seeds.

Design the function that generates a number from the seed to be one-to-one.

@EricPostpischil that would indeed work, but I have made a mistake in my question, I will update it. The number generated is a random number between bounds, like a number between 1 and 10.

Seeds from 0 to 100 cannot all generate different numbers from 1 to 10.

@EricPostpischil that is true. The only goal I have is to be sure that the current seed minus one ('the previous') does not give the same generated number.

I think this question is extremely interesting, and would be much more likely to get good answers if it was asked on math.stackexchange.com rather that on stackoverflow.com, but unfortunately math.stackexchange.com is not on the shortlist of stackexchange sites that I can vote to migrate a question to :-(

@ComputerDoggie generally you don't write your own pseudo-random number generator, you use either a PRNG library or PRNG function that's already been exhaustively tested. Is there a reason why you're trying to write your own? (e.g. did you try all the ones that are readily found with a web search and none of them did what you needed? Because if so, your post probably needs a bit more text to explain what you already tried, and why none of those work for your use-case)

For example, starting at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593316/740553 and verifying that the input seeds you're going to use yield distinct sequences would be a great start.

Random number generators generate random numbers with any value. If there is no way that the a number cannot be identical to the next number then it is not a random number generator.

The easiest thing to skip just generating one previous value is to remember the value and not return it if you hit said value. Just draw a new random number (or use the next seed) if the result clashes with the previous result.
If you want to skip more than one value then put the numbers in a FIFO queue and simply reject the next result if the number is in that queue. Remove the numbers from the queue if the queue gets too big.
There are some other ways to get the same result, but those are complex to explain, e.g. generating a number between 0 and m - n where m is the max and n is the amount of numbers already generated, and then starting at the lowest number: add 1 if the number in the set of already generated numbers is lower than the generated value.
Don't call the result of any of these strategies random though; they are semi-random at best.

These solutions focus on multiple random values from a single seed, but they work just as well for different seeds: reject the seed if it generates the same random number.
