# Implementation of random number generator

Tags: c++, c, random, implementation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does a random number generator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716308/how-does-a-random-number-generator-work)

I am looking for internal implementation of a random number generator in C/C++.Basically I am interested to know, what exactly happens when rand() is called. After all machine follows definite set of instructions, how can it be random!
Edit: Want to know how can I implement one in C/C++.

Comment: This is why it is not *random*, it is *pseudo random*

Comment: Because it's not really random: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: Implementation? if i don't want to use library function.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator. C++11 lets you use Mersenne twisters etc, too, with `<random>`, which work out a whole lot better.

Comment: Other closely related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584566/pseudo-random-number-generator, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114043/random-number-generation-in-c11-how-to-generate-how-do-they-work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're *pseudo-random* number generators, not truly random ones. This is often a *good* thing since it allows you to reproduce bugs more easily where "random" numbers are involved.

You *can* get random number generators, such as reading `/dev/random` under Linux but the normal ones that ship with C libraries generally aren't.

The simplest one are linear congruential generators where:

> `nx+1 = (nx * A + C) modulo M`

with suitably chosen values of `A`, `C` and `M`.

[Wikipedia's page on LCGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) gives some sample values used by various implementations. For example, the `glibc` one listed there has `A = 1103515245, C = 12345, M = 2^31` so it's a simple thing like:

```
static unsigned int seed = 1;
void srand (int newseed) {
    seed = (unsigned)newseed & 0x7fffffffU;
}
int rand (void) {
    seed = (seed * 1103515245U + 12345U) & 0x7fffffffU;
    return (int)seed;
}
```

> Aside: The `glibc` implementation still has this generator within it (called the Type 0 generator) but it also has a fancier trinomial generator as well, which is (presumably) better.

There are also more complex ones (such as the Mersenne twister) that have a much greater cycle time (time before starting to repeat).

Any truly random generator must use a truly random input source which is why `/dev/random` will sometimes block "waiting for entropy", while `/dev/urandom` won't.

"Truly" random sources may be affected by timing between keystrokes, data entered by users, the contents of network packets, disk I/O patterns, time taken for an ICMP response to come back over the network and all sorts of other wondrous, mostly non-deterministic things.

Unless you're heavily into crypto, normal random number generators should be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple pseudo random algorithm:

```
//generates pseudo random series of numbers 0...RAND_MAX - 1 with uniform distribution, starting with 0

static const int A = 15342; // any number in (0, RAND_MAX)
static const int C = 45194; // any number in [0, RAND_MAX)
static const RAND_MAX = 100000;

int rand()
{
    static int prev = 0; //seed. any number in [0, RAND_MAX)
    prev = ( prev * A + C ) % RAND_MAX;
    return prev;
}
```

You can read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Comment: Those are very poorly chosen values for A, C and RAND_MAX by the way. All your numbers will be multiples of 5000 :-) Relatively prime numbers tend to give a better distribution.

Comment: @paxdiablo: agree, randomized them a bit ) But in any case it will give a uniform distribution. Choosing good numbers require more research

Comment: That static var `prev` does not seem to ever be updated.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, the random generators of RAM machines are not truly random, they are [*pseudo-random*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

You can always have a look at the java source of [java.util.Random](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Random.java.html).

Specifically - the method `next(int bits)` is what you are looking for.

```
protected int next(int bits) {
      long oldseed, nextseed;
      AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
      do {
            oldseed = seed.get();
            nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
      } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
      return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

(*) This answer fits for a previous version of the question, which was tagged as java and did not ask specifically for C++.