# to force system seed for Javascript mat.random() method

Tags: javascript, random, seeding

I would like to know how I could force the system seed each time I call math.random() method on JavaScript.
Thanks
Roge

Comment: You can't seed `Math.random`.

Comment: JS's pseudo-random number generator `Math.random()` uses platform-dependent methods. On a browser environment, implementations usually seed from the OS's time I believe.

Comment: To add to @FabrícioMatté said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344312/how-is-randomness-achieved-with-math-random-in-javascript

Comment: @Blender thanks. So, I can't seed math.random on JS. I will post another question about this in a new post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the random engine for Java automatically re-seeds itself as necessary.  It's a pretty well designed system.  If you feel like your random numbers aren't random enough, try doing a benchmark test on 10,000 random numbers and see what kind of distribution you get.

Usually when I feel my numbers aren't random enough, it's because I'm putting too much focus on a small number of random generations that don't have the depth of variety I'm hoping for.

Comment: Don't misspell Java for JS please.