# Getting random value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

Guys i am trying to get random values when click a button and made that code but when i click somehow one value repeat itself 4 times like "k0k2k4k6" , "n0n2n4n6".
Why this happenning?Cos its not a coincidence.
Thanks in advance! [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e96yeaby/)

```js
$(function() {
  var words = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  var myLength = 8;

  function random() {
    for (var i = 0; i < myLength; i++) {
      $('#content').append(word + i++);
    }
  }

  $('#button').click(function() {
    random();
  });

});
```

```css
#content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 50px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: And what _should_ happen?

Comment: Move `var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];` into the `for`-loop

Comment: Because your maximum limit is 8 and you are incrementing twice, one in the `for` loop and inside there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344312/how-is-randomness-achieved-with-math-random-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is it generating 4 times?**

*Because your maximum limit is 8 and you are incrementing twice, one in the `for` loop and inside there.*

Moving the `word` (generated dynamically) definition inside the loop solves it:

```js
$(function() {
  var words = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  var myLength = 8;

  function random() {
    // Also I would clear before generating new:
    $('#content').html("");
    for (var i = 0; i < myLength; i++) {
      var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
      $('#content').append(word + i++);
    }
  }

  $('#button').click(function() {
    random();
  });

});
```

```css
#content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 50px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your variables into the function:

```
$(function() {

 function random() {
   var words = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
   var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
   var myLength = 8;
   for (var i = 0; i < myLength; i++) {
     $('#content').append(word + i++);
   }
 }

 $('#button').click(function() {
   random();
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  var words = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  var myLength = 8;

  function random() {
    var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

    for (var i = 0; i < myLength; i++) {
      $('#content').append(word + i++);
    }
  }

  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('#content').html('');
    random();
  });

});
```