# attachEvent or addEventListener - stored where?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

In jQuery, if I do this...

```
$('a').click(function(){
    // Do something 
});
```

...the click event is stored at `$('a').data('events')` and I can fetch it like so:

```
jQuery.each($('a').data('events'), function(i, event){  
    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){
        if(handler.type.toString() == 'click')
        {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

An event that is attached via `attachEvent` or `addEventListener` will obviously not appear in `$('a').data('events')`. Is there anything I can iterate in its place? I assume they're queued up somewhere, but I can't find documentation to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You cannot access that information

Comment: Sorry for not believing you out of the box, but if you have some documentation to back up that claim I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get code installed at the beginning of the page, you can record all subsequent listeners in your own data structure with this kind of hook: [Why does Google +1 record my mouse movements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667544/why-does-google-1-record-my-mouse-movements/6668055#6668055).

I know of no way to access the existing listeners.

Comment: This looks promising as hell!

Comment: I'm going to test this this weekend - I haven't forgotten about this idea :)

Answer (score 4):

From [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html):

> One problem of the current implementation of W3C’s event registration
>   model is that you can’t find out if any event handlers are already
>   registered to an element. In the traditional model you could do:
>
> ```
> alert(element.onclick)
> ```
>
> and you see the function that’s registered to it, or undefined if
>   nothing is registered. Only in its very recent [DOM Level 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20020208/changes.html) W3C
>   adds an eventListenerList to store a list of event handlers that are
>   currently registered on an element. This functionality is not yet
>   supported by any browser, it’s too new. However, the problem has been
>   addressed.

Comment: That's ancient. DOM Level 3 events is from 2002. "Not supported by any browser" in 2002 is ... well IE7 came out in 2006 and look how far we've come.

Comment: @AlienWebGuy even so browsers do not support it.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Introduced in DOM Level 2:
interface EventTarget {
  void               addEventListener(in DOMString type, 
                                      in EventListener listener, 
                                      in boolean useCapture);
  void               removeEventListener(in DOMString type, 
                                         in EventListener listener, 
                                         in boolean useCapture);
  boolean            dispatchEvent(in Event evt)
                                        raises(EventException);
  // Introduced in DOM Level 3:
  readonly attribute EventListenerList  eventListeners;
};
```

So `el.eventListeners` contains all event listeners attached to `el` using `el.addEventListener`.

You would need to use a shim to deal with browser support. Currently Chrome 12 and Firefox 5 do not support this

Comment: How lame. One more reason to use JQuery, seriously.

Comment: @AlienWebGuy not a reason to use jQuery. It's a reason to use a cross browser polyfill. jQuery is a particular polyfill (and a rather mediocre one at that)

Comment: Bold statement which contradicts the mass opinion. What polyfill do you recommend then?