# generating "random" numbers that are the same every time with javascript (i.e. seeded random numbers)

Tags: javascript, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create my own JavaScript Random Number generator that I can also set the seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/how-to-create-my-own-javascript-random-number-generator-that-i-can-also-set-the-s)

So, if I have this function:

```
function randArr(count, low, high) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
        result.push(seededRand(low, high));
    }
    return result;
}
```

every time I call `randArr(5, 1, 100)` I would get the same array back, e.g. `[54, 23, 1, 9, 15]`.

Update: I think this is a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/how-to-create-my-own-javascript-random-number-generator-that-i-can-also-set-the-s), but since commentors seem confused, the question is, how to write `seededRand()`?

Comment: Can we see the `seededRand` function?

Comment: Mandatory Cartoon in response to question title: http://www.hutter1.net/private/random.gif

Comment: @Oded: He gets same array result always.

Comment: found this, which seems to be covering the same ground http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/how-to-create-my-own-javascript-random-number-generator-that-i-can-also-set-the-s

Comment: @Jacob: no, that's what I'm looking for. :)

Comment: @Sarfraz - possibly. It is unclear whether he wants that or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a random number generator where you could set a seed at the beginning.

I needed to do that a while ago in ActionScript and I used [Blum Blum Shub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub), because its quite easy to implement. Implementing a [mersene twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) also should be possible, and should give "better random" results.

Comment: Blum Blum Shub is pretty good, but it does cost a bit more on the processing. Mersenne Twister algorithms are mostly seeded by multiply with carry algorithms. And if you're going to use Mersenne Twister to seed a javascript rand() function, why not use it in the first place? For simple applications, I think multiply-with-carry generators suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You want that seededRand function?

You could implement a pseudorandom number function by yourself.

I googled for "javascript mersenne twister" and for example found this page:
http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/JAVASCRIPT/java-script.html

If the license suits you, you could use that.