# Javascript - generate value from time (ms)

Tags: javascript, time

I need to generate some values on Javascript, by clicking on a button, that can't be the same of previous values. I think to generate it from time in ms (in fact I think nobody can't click a button faster than a ms, right?).

What do you think? And how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Comment: or `+new Date`, a little hackish ;)

Answer (score 2):

yes, I think its pretty solid to use complete datetime (including milliseconds) as a seed for generating a random number.

```
var currentTime = new Date(),
    time = currentTime.getTime();
```

Check out related question:
[Seedable JavaScript random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/how-to-create-my-own-javascript-random-number-generator-that-i-can-also-set-the-s)

Also, see David Bau's blog for more information on seeding:
http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html#more