# Procedural functions with seed (like road generator)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, procedural-programming, procedural-generation

I've searched around but didn't find a solid answer. I'm building a game in AS3. I have no issue generating random map (2D tiles) for my game, which is basically made of random numbers.
How do I obtain the exact same result all the time passing a seed parameter to my function ?

```
function generate(__xt:uint, __yt:uint){
  var rnd:int;
  for (var i:uint=0; i < __xt; i++){
     for(var j:uint=0; j < __yt; j++){
         rnd = Math.round(Math.random());
         ...
     }   
  }
}
```

Comment: You should seed the Math.random() function with the same value every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `Math.random()` doesn't support seeding and if you need it, you have to implement your own `PRNG`. Take a look in this answer [Seedable JavaScript random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/seedable-javascript-random-number-generator) for the `JS`, it's quite easy to port one of the answers to `as3`.

Answer (score 1):

[Grant Skinner developed great library](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2008/01/source_code_see.html) for generating random numbers, I would recommend to [use it](https://github.com/gskinner/AS3Libs/tree/master/Rndm), not Math.random()

> ... I decided to build a class to generate random numbers based on a seed number. This is also handy for other uses like statistics, testing, and game development (ex. synchronizing or replaying game play). It was quite straightforward, because Flash Player already has a mechanism for generating a series of random numbers based on a seed hidden away in its APIs â BitmapData.noise().