# How to take an existing number and generate a random number based on it? [javascript]

Tags: javascript, random

I want to take a single digit number input by the user and generate another single digit random number based on it.  A real world equivalent would be a roulette or slot machine that starts at a specific value and then randomizes.

This will generate a random number from 1-10, but does not involve any existing number as input.

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking for.  Is the number the user is inputting a max value of the random?  If it is not... how are you determining the min/max value of what your random function should return?

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem. Why doesn't your solution work? How will the random number be related to the input?

Comment: if the user enters the starting value of the random number then its: `var randomnumber= (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) ) + user_input`

Comment: How will the random number be based on the original?

Comment: he is asking for a seeded RNG

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
```

Also you can refer and use the following code based on your need

```
function randomNumberInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the user enters the starting value of the random number then its:

```
var randomnumber= (Math.floor(Math.random()*10) ) + user_input
```

example user inputs 5 and math.floor(random number) is 3, then your actual random number will be 5+3=8

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you're looking for is a seeded random number generator, the seed being the pre-existing number. This isn't possible directly with Math.Random as it just uses the current time as a seed. Take a look here for workarounds though.

[Seeding the random number generator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/javascript-random-seeds)

[Seedable JavaScript random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/seedable-javascript-random-number-generator)

both point to this link: http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html

where a seeded random number generated has been created and is downloadable here
https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom

or for a simpler solution the second answer in the first link:

```
var seed = 1;
function random() {
var x = Math.sin(seed++) * 10000;
return x - Math.floor(x);
}
```

credit to @Antti Sykäri for that code