# Generate the same semi random number on two machines

Tags: javascript, random

I was wondering if there is a way to generate the same semi random number on two machines at the same time. Here is an example of how I am currently getting my randoms.

```
var randomValue = generateRandom( -200, 200 );

function generateRandom( min, max ) 
{
    min = Math.ceil( min );
    max = Math.floor( max );
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) + min );
}
```

What I can do is send message between the two devices. I don't know if that will help because randomValue is being called within a function. I was thinking maybe we can use a timer or something to generate the value on both machines.

Comment: If you can communicate between the machines, why do you need to generate the number on both places? Do it once and share... (And no, built-in pseudo random generator has no seeding function so you can't synchronize it between machines)

Comment: So I'm worried that the function that is calling randomValue will need the value before the message is received.

Comment: Generate a collection of numbers ahead of time then

Comment: I was thinking about that but the parameters change on the fly

Comment: Pick an [RNG algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators), and give it the same seed.

Comment: What parameters? The pseudo random generator is parameterless

Comment: Sorry bad choice of words. The min, max values will being changing.

Comment: RNG algorithm sounds interesting. What would you recommend for the seed and how would I go about making sure they both get the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a list of random values between 0 & 1 using the built-in generator (`Math.random()`) ahead of time on one of the machines ("master"), share it with the slave(s).

Wherever you need a concrete value, use the next number in that list with the current parameters (min-max range) and you'll have identical numbers on all machines.

If you "run out" of values, generate and transmit another batch (again, ahead of time).

Comment: This sounds very simple and effective. I can generate the array of random numbers and pass it to the slaves but I'm not sure how I to "use the next number in that list with the current parameters (min-max range) " . Can you alter the example above to demonstrate that?

Comment: Ooooo I see. Just replace Math.random() with the array value. Stupid question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JohnBob The example above is incomplete and missing the communication part, but if all machines (master & slaves) have the same array of values, and all use up the same value every time, then all machines know the next value. Basically this means you need to replace `Math.random()` with something like `randomValues.pop()` or `randomValues.shift()`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using 'seedable' random number generator, which is discussed in [Seedable JavaScript random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/seedable-javascript-random-number-generator) ?

And there is an implementation on github : https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom

Answer (score 0):

To genrate a same identical number on two machines at the same time.

1. Genrate the current timestamp `new Date().getTime()`
2. Reverse this number (This will sufficiently be random everytime)
3. Get it in the range of (-200,200) by devision and multiplication with constants.

This number will be identical on two machines at a given time.