# Use Timestemp as Seed in Seeded Random Generator but Output is Always the Same

Tags: javascript, date, random, functional-programming

I started to make a dungeon-game that creates randomly new dungeons. There for I have the `seededRandom` function. Judging from my test, this function is correct.

```
function seededRandom (seed, min = 0, max = 1) {
  const random = ((seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280) / 233280
  return min + random * (max - min)
}
```

It will be called inside the `createDungeon` function with `Date.now()` as argument for `seed`

```
function createDungeon(numberOfRooms, rooms = []) {
  ...
  const randomWidth = Math.floor(Generator.seededRandom(Date.now(), 10, 20))
  const randomHeight = Math.floor(Generator.seededRandom(Date.now(), 10, 20))
  const randomTopLeftCoordinate = Coordinate.create(
    Math.floor(Generator.seededRandom(Date.now(), 10, previousRoom.width)), // x position
    Math.floor(Generator.seededRandom(Date.now(), 10, previousRoom.height)) // y position
  )
  ...
}
```

Inside my tests I logged the `start timestemp`, `createDungeon return value` and `end timestemp` and apparently `Date.now()` is not exactly enough.

```
1502301604075 // start timestemp
[ 
  { width: 19, height: 19, topLeftCoordinate: { x: 18, y: 18 } },
  ...
  { width: 19, height: 19, topLeftCoordinate: { x: 18, y: 18 } },
  { width: 19, height: 19, topLeftCoordinate: { x: 18, y: 18 } } 
] 
1502301604075 // end timestemp
```

### Question

What could I use as seed to have in each object a different value based on the seed?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/seedable-javascript-random-number-generator

Comment: @BenM I know this post but I don't know how this could help me..

Comment: It includes plenty of examples of seeded RNGs in Javascript...

Comment: I'm sorry but the promlem isnt the RNG.. its the timestemp

Comment: Read the answers, it demonstrates more suitable seeds for the RNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments mentioned: there are several seeded random number libraries out there that should be perfectly suitable for your application. I used [this one](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom) in my example.

The key is to create a seeded random number generator *before* getting the dungeon's properties:

```
const DungeonCreator = seed => {
  const rnd = new Math.seedrandom(seed);

  return nrOfRooms => ({
    width: inRange(rnd(), 0, 20),
    height: inRange(rnd(), 0, 20),
    topLeft: {
      x: inRange(rnd(), 0, 10),
      y: inRange(rnd(), 0, 10)
    },
    nrOfRooms
  })
}
```

This method returns a dungeon generator that will give you a new dungeon every time you call it. *However*, generators that were created using the same *seed*, will give you the same dungeons.

Although not "pure", it makes the code testable.

```js
const DungeonCreator = seed => {
  const rnd = new Math.seedrandom(seed);
  
  return nrOfRooms => ({
    width: inRange(rnd(), 0, 20),
    height: inRange(rnd(), 0, 20),
    topLeft: {
      x: inRange(rnd(), 0, 10),
      y: inRange(rnd(), 0, 10)
    },
    nrOfRooms
  })
}

const myDungeonCreator1 = DungeonCreator("seedOne");
const myDungeonCreator2 = DungeonCreator("seedTwo");
const myDungeonCreator3 = DungeonCreator("seedOne");

const roomSizes = [1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 6];

const dungeons1 = roomSizes.map(myDungeonCreator1);
const dungeons2 = roomSizes.map(myDungeonCreator2);
const dungeons3 = roomSizes.map(myDungeonCreator3);

console.log("Creator 1 & 3 created the same dungeons:",
  dungeonsEqual(dungeons1, dungeons3)
);

console.log("Creator 1 & 2 created the same dungeons:",
  dungeonsEqual(dungeons1, dungeons2)
);

console.log("Creator 2 & 3 created the same dungeons:",
  dungeonsEqual(dungeons2, dungeons3)
);


// Util
function inRange(value, min, max) {
  return min + Math.floor(value * (max - min));
};

function dungeonEqual(d1, d2) {
  return (
  d1.nrOfRooms === d2.nrOfRooms &&
  d1.width === d2.width &&
  d1.height === d2.height &&
  d1.topLeft.x === d2.topLeft.x &&
  d1.topLeft.y === d2.topLeft.y
  );
}

function dungeonsEqual(ds1, ds2) {
  return ds1.every((d, i) => dungeonEqual(d, ds2[i]));
};
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/seedrandom/2.4.3/seedrandom.min.js">
</script>
```