# Javascript - return a random value based on month

Tags: javascript

Is there any way I can generate a random number from 1 to 4 based on the current month.

So in a month it will return the same value, a different value the next month and a different one the coming month and so on?

Comment: you tried what so far?

Comment: You are probably looking for seeding. It is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/seedable-javascript-random-number-generator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 0):

```
function random(seed) {
    var x = Math.sin(seed++) * 10000;
    return x - Math.floor(x);
}
var d = new Date();
rand = random(d.getMonth());
console.log(rand*4);
```

if you want integers

```
console.log(Math.floor(rand*4));
```