# deterministic samples from multivariate-normal-js

Tags: javascript, numpy, distribution

I am using [multivariate-normal-js](https://github.com/tulip/multivariate-normal-js) which is a port of NumPy's `random.multivariate_normal`. However, I need to be able to produce deterministic results. Is there any way do to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multivariate-normal-js` uses the inverse transform method to generate samples from a standard normal distribution, and it uses `Math.random()` to generate the uniformly distributed random inputs to the inverse transform.  So to be able to reproduce a (pseudo-)random sequence, you would need to be able to set the random seed for `Math.random()`.  According to [the documentation for `Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), this is not possible.

So the short answer is no, you can't do it.  But see [Seeding the random number generator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript) and [Seedable JavaScript random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/seedable-javascript-random-number-generator) (and maybe search for more recent discussions) if you want to try to work around that limitation of `Math.random()`.  If you did that, you would have to replace the call to `Math.random()` at [line 22 of distribution.js](https://github.com/tulip/multivariate-normal-js/blob/38dd68f5bb2a291d38ff053d1c13e74d33fd8bc8/src/distribution.js#L22) with the appropriate call of your "seedable" random number generator to generate a random value from the uniform distribution on [0, 1).