# AWS Lambda bad at generating random numbers?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function that is generating a random number from 0 to 22 on every invocation. However, I don't feel like the number is truly random, as I often get the same number back in succession when I quickly run the function multiple times.

The runtime is `nodejs8.10` and I'm simply calling `Math.floor(23*Math.random())` to generate the number.

To debug this, I ran the function 78 times over a duration of about 20 minutes, downloaded the logs from CloudWatch Logs and put the numbers in a file called `numbers.txt`:

```
$ cat numbers.txt | tr "\n" " "
5 22 19 7 14 3 14 19 8 1 15 4 7 17 6 5 19 11 18 17 15 5 0 20 11 20 12 12 14 16 5 13 19 19 10 18 21 19 12 20 8 11 16 19 1 1 4 5 2 5 11 3 20 4 2 12 3 6 2 17 20 11 16 1 20 22 1 21 15 17 1 1 1 2 5 5 13 12
```

Here's how often each number was generated:

```
$ cat numbers.txt | sort | uniq -c
1 0
8 1
1 10
5 11
5 12
2 13
3 14
3 15
3 16
4 17
2 18
7 19
4 2
6 20
2 21
2 22
3 3
3 4
8 5
2 6
2 7
2 8
```

Numbers 1 and 5 were both generated 8 times each, while 9 wasn't generated even once.

Are there any gotchas with randomness in AWS Lambda? Can I do something to get more random numbers?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think these values look non-random.

Taking 78 samples from 23 values might be suspicious if it **WERE** consistently uniform.  Taking 100,000 samples from 23 values would look suspicious if it were **NOT** uniform.

Simulating in python to demonstrate.

Your current setup (78 samples of 23 values):

```
import random
import numpy as np

num_vals = 23
num_samples = 78

results = [0] * num_vals

for i in range(num_samples):
    results[random.randint(0,num_vals - 1)] += 1

plt.bar(np.arange(23), results)
```

[image]

Here the most sampled value was selected 10x more often than the least sampled value.  Run the same thing, but change `num_samples` to 10,000 and it get obviously more uniform (like you'd expect).

[image]

So this was one experiment with these values...  if I run your setup (78 samples of 23) 10,000 times, it always has a highly skewed sample rate.

```
num_vals = 23
num_samples = 78
num_tests = 10000

max_minus_min = []

for j in range(num_tests):

    results = [0] * num_vals

    for i in range(num_samples):
        results[random.randint(0,num_vals - 1)] += 1

    max_minus_min.append(max(results) - min(results))

plt.hist(max_minus_min, bins=25)
```

More than 1/3 of the 10,000 simulations had `max - min` >= 8, so I don't think your results look that anomalous.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue you would have is not with AWS Lambda but with the Math.random library. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/seedable-javascript-random-number-generator) related Stack Overflow question. Consider [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) for an introduction to the theory of random number generation.