# What is the initial seed used in Math.random() in javascript, to generate Pseudo random number?

Tags: javascript, random

```
var randomNumber = Math.random();
```

What is the initial seed used in this function?

Edited --
I don't know why this question was marked duplicate with the question which asked the working of this method.

I just want to know the exact initial seed used to implement this. I just used this method to get a random number. My program was running on latest version of the Google Chrome browser.
So can someone please help me? I am just a beginner, Advanced stuff scare me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The details of `Math.random()` are left up to each implementation.

Comment: Which implementation is used in The latest version of Google Chrome? I don't wanna see the implementation though. Just curious about the particular seed used.

Comment: See: [Seeding the random number generator in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521295/seeding-the-random-number-generator-in-javascript), [Seedable JavaScript random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/seedable-javascript-random-number-generator)