# Generate number between range, from other number in JS

Tags: javascript, numbers

I need a function that will generate a number between two other numbers, based on a given number.

If the function looks like this:

```
function getNumber(minimum, maximum, number) {
  ...
}
```

And if I input this:

```
getNumber(0, 3, 12837623);
```

It should process the third argument, and give me a number between 0 and 3 (inclusive or non-inclusive), based on it, and if I run it multiple times with the same arguments I should get the same number.

It is kind of similar to a random number function, except it uses the given number instead of a random one.

```
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}

function getNumber(min, max, number) {
  //uses third argument instead of random number
  return Math.floor(number * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a Seeded PsuedoRandom number generator (lots of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424292/seedable-javascript-random-number-generator)).

A pseudorandom number generator would always give the same series with a particular seed. Just use the third argument as your seed.

Infact `Math.random()` is also a pseduorandom number generator, the only problem is its seed cannot be [chosen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random). This is the reason Math.random() should NEVER be used in cryptography related implementations. (there is `window.crypto.getRandomValues()` for it.)

So your new random number function should be

```
function getRndInteger(min, max, seed) {
  return Math.floor(SeedRandom(seed) * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}
```